# No wireless for Intel Corporation 7260 version 63

Tags: wireless, intel-wireless, xps, 13.10

I have a Dell XPS 12 running Ubuntu 13.10 and it doesn't appear to find it's wireless.  I have tried the suggestions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/322511/no-wireless-with-intel-centrino-advanced-n-7260) but they made no difference

```
peter@xps:/lib/firmware$ ls -l /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 682892 Aug  4 12:50 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode
peter@xps:/lib/firmware$ sudo lshw -c network
  *-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: Wireless 7260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       version: 63
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f7c00000-f7c01fff

peter@xps:~/backports-3.10-2$ grep IWL7260_UCODE_API_MAX drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwl-7000.c 
#define IWL7260_UCODE_API_MAX   7
    .ucode_api_max = IWL7260_UCODE_API_MAX,         \
peter@xps:~/backports-3.10-2$ dmesg | grep iwl
peter@xps:~/backports-3.10-2$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

peter@xps:~$ find / -name *7260-6*
peter@xps:~$ find / -name *7260-7*
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode 

peter@xps:~$ dmesg | grep -i -A 20 intel
[ 1318.013278] Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux, in-tree:d
[ 1318.013281] Copyright(c) 2003-2013 Intel Corporation
[ 1318.015154] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[ 1318.015157] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[ 1318.015159] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1318.015161] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1318.015162] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1318.015164] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1318.015165] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
```

---

What I have found is that it appears to be loading an old version of the firmware but I don't know how or why

```
peter@xps:/lib/firmware$ modinfo iwlwifi | grep 7260
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-6.ucode
peter@xps:/lib/firmware$ ls *7260-6*
ls: cannot access *7260-6*: No such file or directory
```

Any suggestions of how to get this setup very welcome.

Comment: Please confirm that you made the changes to iwl-7000.c, compiled backports-3.10.2 and loaded iwlwifi. What interesting clues are in: dmesg | grep iwl?

Comment: I believe it's the loading of the iwlwifi which failed as I see `iwlwifi-7260-6.ucode` is loaded.  I had a version `iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode` already, and replacing it didn't help. Not sure why it doesn't load this anyway.

Comment: The change to iwl-7000.c is supposed to fix that. You might also rename -6.ucode to -6.bak so it can't load and see if it helps. You will need to unload and reload iwlwifi or reboot for the change to be effective.

Comment: @chili555 That is what confuses me. No such file exists. Only the `-7.ucode` exists.

Comment: What is the exact message in dmesg that says -6 is loading. Maybe we can deduce what to fix in iwl-7000.c. dmesg | grep -e firm -e ucode

Comment: @chili555 dmesg doesn't mention 7260 at all, nor anything to do with `-6` and wifi. Only `modinfo` suggests it is loaded.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10086/discussion-between-chili555-and-peter-lawrey)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I suggest you download this to your desktop: http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v3.11-rc3/backports-3.11-rc3-1.tar.bz2 Right-click it and select 'Extract Here.' Now open a terminal and do:

```
cd Desktop/backports-3.11-rc3-1/
make defconfig-iwlwifi
make
sudo make install
```

Now download the required firmware here:  https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/egrumbach/linux-firmware.git/plain/iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode Now open a terminal and do:

```
sudo cp ~/Desktop/iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode /lib/firmware/  <--or wherever you downloaded it
sudo modprobe -r iwldvm  <--If it is not loaded, OK, please proceed
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi <--If it is not loaded, OK, please proceed
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

Your wireless should now be working.

For those that can't get the ucode file from the above link use this link:
http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking/000005511.html

Comment: For those who ask, the ucode file comes from the Debian package: http://packages.debian.org/fr/sid/firmware-iwlwifi

Comment: Thanks, that helped! Does this mean though that now I can't update the kernel packages via system update?

Comment: @DmitryPashkevich- Yes, you can, but you will have to repeat the compile process above. The firmware part need not be repeated.

Comment: yeah that's what I actually meant :) thanks. I *can* update the kernel but I would have to reinstall the backport again

Comment: @DmitryPashkevich- Exactly!

Comment: For those that prefer getting things from original sources, the firmware can be found at: http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi#Firmware

Comment: Apparently the new 3.10 kernel should work just fine.

Comment: Worked also for me (12.04)

Comment: Also worked for me with Advanced-N 6235

Comment: @chili555: +1. I have been plagued by a similar wireless adapter problem: http://askubuntu.com/questions/612138/wireless-automatic-disconnected?noredirect=1#comment862486_612138 Could you take a look? Thanks.

Comment: This answer is great. Solves my problem of no wlan0 after removing 3.16 and installed 3.19. followed this answer, I download the backports 3.19 and the corresponding intel wifi firmware. The only difference I did is "make -j". saves me a little time though.

Answer (score 2):

After installing Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty on my Dell Vostro 5470 laptop, I had the same problem. Installing the newest driver worked for me, no need for backports.

It can be found here:
http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi#Firmware

In the driver files, there is a Readme with instructions, but here is how to do it:

Download the driver on your Desktop:
http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=iwlwifi-7260-ucode-22.24.8.0.tgz

Extract the contents on your Desktop.

```
sudo cp ~/Desktop/iwlwifi-7260-ucode-22.15.8.0/iwlwifi-7260-8.ucode /lib/firmware/
```

Restart.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Were there any additional steps you used?

Comment: No, just these 4 steps. Now I am using 16.04 with the same laptop, and the wifi works out of the box.