# To enable wireless on Thinkpad t440s

Tags: 12.04, 13.04, wireless, thinkpad

2 weeks after I bought `t440s` with `Windows 8` bundled, I'm freaked out with it and want to replace with `Precise`. Using USB boot to make sure if it's run although the device looks like already [certified by Canonical](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201308-14073/), Ubuntu can't find wireless device. I've found [a workaround for a similar issue](http://exain.wordpress.com/2011/10/16/wireless-on-ubuntu-11-10-and-lenovo-thinkpad-e420/), I still don't know what to do.

The same URL from above says:

```
Network
    Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 6
    Ericsson Business Mobile Networks BV Unknown
```

Also,

```
$ lsmod|grep intel
:
snd_hda_intel
kvm_intel
aesni_intel
ghash_clmuni_intel, aesni_intel
intel_ips
```

I'm not an expert at all with devices...I'd appreciate solution. Thanks!

---

**Update**) I'm required to use Ubuntu 12.04.

---

**Update-2**) I upgraded to 13.04, hopelessly expecting that doing so would just resolve the issue. Ended up seeing no improvement. I found the model of wireless module is `Intel Wireless-N 7260` from [this page](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Review-Lenovo-ThinkPad-T440s-20AQ-S00500-Notebook.103199.0.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question since I finally got wifi working on my `t440s` with Ubuntu `13.04`.

I did exactly what is recommended [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/331696/24203), except that I obtained `Wireless 7260` [from here](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi) instead of the link in the answer that seems someone's dropbox.

Although [from this website](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Review-Lenovo-ThinkPad-T440s-20AQ-S00500-Notebook.103199.0.html) the wifi module bundled on `t440s` is `Intel Wireless-N 7260`, the driver I mentioned above, `Intel Wireless 7260` (without `N`), seems to be working fine.

---

Update) After some while, wifi has been working fine with a following few tweaks:

- Every time I reboot the OS, I need to run:

  sudo modprobe iwlwifi
- Though only occasionally, wifi device goes inactive and I have to build `iwlwifi` again same as in the link above:

  `cd Desktop/backports-3.11-rc3-1/
  make defconfig-iwlwifi
  make
  sudo make install`

Comment: **Note for all new owners of the T440s:** The current LTS-Version Ubuntu 14.04 detects all hardware components automatically, including WiFi and WWAN. =)

Answer (score 1):

Try going to the computer manufacter's web site and look for the wireless drivers for Windows and use windows wireless drivers from the Ubuntu web store. I hope that works, I have never had any wi-fi issues, so if this doesn't work, I'm sorry.

Comment: Good to know about `Windows Wireless Drivers`. Now I'm looking for the way to use it on USB boot (I want to verify if Ubuntu works on this machine first by USB)..

Comment: When you made the bootable USB did you set it to preserve space? If so then you can install windows wireless drivers on the USB. If you didn't I would suggest trying again on putting Ubuntu on the USB and preserve some space.

Answer (score 0):

As my answer in [wireless not enabled in 12.04, Lenovo T440s](https://askubuntu.com/questions/401703/wireless-not-enabled-in-12-04-lenovo-t440s/419232#419232) points out, if you want to get wireless in 12.04 you have to use a newer kernel version, 3.11 or later. I also have Intel Wireless 7260 (not sure about the -N) and either of the following works:

- Installing a newer kernel version, by installing linux-generic-lts-saucy, in 12.04.3 or older.
- Using the recently released and latest version, 12.04.4, from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Note that Ubuntu 13.10 also works out of the box (but I personally prefer LTS versions).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems in the beginning, trying 12.04 and 13.04

It was solved after upgrading to 13.10 where all drivers where detected automatically.