# wireless not enabled in 12.04, Lenovo T440s

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my Lenovo T440s, but I can't get the wireless to work. The adapter is a `Intel Wireless 7260`, as shown here: http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201308-14073/components/

I installed while having a network cable plugged in, so all updates were also downloaded/installed during installation.

When I press on the network-"half circle" in the top, right corner it just says "not enabled" at the wireless. What is wrong here, it seems like 12.04 should support it from [this](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201308-14073/components/).

Comment: Download http://homepage.univie.ac.at/markus.gronemann/ubook-specs/lenovo/hmm/t440s_hmm_en_sp40a25360_01.pdf which will be handy to have on hand. Fn-F8 disables wireless as per page 41. Is wireless on or off with that key?

Comment: when I just press F8 it disables/enables bluetooth, but nothing happens when I press Fn+F8

Comment: Duplicate of: askubuntu.com/questions/322511/no-wireless-with-intel-centrino-advanced-n-7260/

Comment: @K7AAY When I open `Additional Drivers` it says "It says "no proprietary drivers are in use on this system"

Comment: After compiling the driver as in my link, if your wireless is unstable,substitute the revised firmware from here: https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/egrumbach/linux-firmware.git/plain/iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode

Comment: @chili555 I tried following the guide, but it still doesn't work at all. Just says "not enabled"

Comment: Did you compile the driver from backports, load the firmware to /lib/modules and then modprobe iwlwifi or something less?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the T440s and Ubuntu 12.04 is running wonderfully. But to get it running smoothly and also the wireless adapter, you will need to have the newer Linux kernel installed.

So make sure you are connected to the internet (by using Ethernet or a phone tethering). Then run the following command in terminal;

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-saucy
```

This will install the latest `3.11 kernel`. Once it's done (only when it's done), restart your laptop.

Also, I just noticed that the 12.04.4 version was released very recently. With that version the above is no longer needed and everything should work out of the box.
So to all new people installing Ubuntu 12.04 on a T440s, please make sure to have the latest version.

You may get it from here: [Download Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

Answer (score 0):

Please search for hardware-drivers or Drivers in menu open that up and keep your cabled network connected, you will see your wireless card disabled there than enable it and everything will work just fine.

1. Click on Ubuntu Icon
2. Search for `Drivers or hardware-drivers`
3. Open that up and enbale your wireless driver from there

It will look like this

[image]

Comment: It says "no proprietary drivers are in use on this system"

Answer (score 0):

Some t440 models do not come with a wireless card. Might be worth checking your devise manager.

We have ordered 50 and had manually install the card in everyone.