# Is re-installation of wireless driver necessary after updating linux headers every time?

Tags: wireless, drivers, kernel, dell

I  updated my laptop with the recommended updates including the "Linux-header 3.8.0-34". After installation, i noticed my wireless was not working. I began troubleshooting and nothing worked. Finally i decided to re install the specific driver for my laptop using the fix from this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/331667/no-wireless-for-intel-corporation-7260-version-63) when i first installed Ubuntu.

It worked! I am happy i got it to work again but my question is do i need to re-install the driver every time i make this kind of update on my system? I'm a bit frustrated with my recently purchased Dell Inspiron 7537 which has been giving me problems but i am wondering if this is a known issue for Ubuntu or is it just another problem with my laptop???

Answer (score 0):

Use DKMS to compile/install modules/drivers that are kernel specific and need to be updated automagically:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DKMS