# can't find wireless for Intel Corporation 7260 on ubuntu 12.04 LTS (3.2.0.57)

Tags: 12.04, wireless, kernel

I followed the post-

[No wireless for Intel Corporation 7260 version 63](https://askubuntu.com/questions/331667/no-wireless-for-intel-corporation-7260-version-63)

but when I run the following command-

`make defconfig-iwlwifi` (executes fine)

```
make
```

I get the an error saying "*** No rule to make target 'card'."

I executed the steps specified on the post on kernel version 3.2.0.29 perfectly, and it worked like a beauty, But once I updated the kernel version to 3.2.0.57 the wifi wasn't available, so I went back to recompile "backport" again as suggested. But this time I got the above error.

(Machine is Lenevo L540)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please boot into 3.2.0-57 and execute as follows:

```
cd Desktop/backports-3.11-rc3-1/
make clean
make defconfig-iwlwifi
make
sudo make install
```

After the addition of 'make clean,' it makes perfectly on my 3.2.0-56 machine.

If you still get an error, please confirm you have installed linux-headers-generic and build-essential. Before you try again, please precede with 'make clean.'

Comment: I'm afraid I get the same error even when I try to run "make clean" .... don't know why...I tried a fresh compilation even by deleting the old directory...

Comment: Any other suggestions to get the wifi working??

Comment: Please see my edit.