# Lenovo ThinkPad s440 network

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, lenovo, thinkpad

Does anybody know how to configure Wi-Fi on a Lenovo ThinkPad s440 with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

I can't configure it even with LAN. Wi-Fi is the first thing I need. I can't find any drivers for Linux. As I see it from ([official specs link](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201306-13872/)) Ubuntu uses "*Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller*" to establish network.

Can anybody suggest a solution? A driver, a way to configure Wi-Fi or anything?

```
$ lspci -nn | grep 0280
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:08b2] (rev 73)
```

Answer (score 1):

I installed iwlwifi module using [instructions from another thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/331667/no-wireless-for-intel-corporation-7260-version-63). I just needed to know my `Intel 7260` to find this answer.

So, steps (by chili555) are:

> I suggest you download this to your desktop:
>   http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v3.11-rc3/backports-3.11-rc3-1.tar.bz2
>   Right-click it and select 'Extract Here.' Now open a terminal and do:

```
cd Desktop/backports-3.11-rc3-1/
make defconfig-iwlwifi
make
sudo make install
```

> Now download the required firmware here:
>   https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/58267392/iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode.zip
>   Please download it to your desktop. Right-click and select 'Extract
>   Here.' Now open a terminal and do:

```
sudo cp Desktop/iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode /lib/firmware/
sudo modprobe -r iwldvm  <--If it is not loaded, OK, please proceed
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi <--If it is not loaded, OK, please proceed
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

UPDATE:
[Intel wireless 7260 driver crashes, how do I work around it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/411475/problem-with-the-intel-wireless-7260-driver/)

Comment: The device quoted above is ethernet, not wireless. It's impossible to propose a better solution without details: lspci -nn | grep 0280. If yours is the Intel 7260 device, there are several threads here about how to install it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I could first define my device, then try to get precise solution.

Comment: May we assume it's now working correctly?

Comment: Yes, everything works now, thank you very much!

Comment: Now I have another problem - [system crash and unstable wifi](http://askubuntu.com/questions/411755/thinkpad-s440-wifi-and-unexpected-system-halt).

Comment: You might try the updated firmware file: askubuntu.com/questions/411475/problem-with-the-intel-wireless-7260-driver/ As for the system crash, I see many of these: "ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed" I am no expert on ACPI problems but I suggest you search for that error and a solution.

Comment: What about this lines in `/var/log/syslog`: `Jan 28 00:58:45 o1dnik-ThinkPad-S3-S440 kernel: [10009.599503] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to create debugfs directory under netdev:wlan0
Jan 28 00:58:45 o1dnik-ThinkPad-S3-S440 kernel: [10009.610319] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: ERROR Transfer event TRB DMA ptr not part of current TD` They are related to only wlan?

Comment: The second message (xhci_hcd) isn't related to wireless. That's related to USB. The first on I have seen only a few times, always related to firmware (!!!) Did you install the newer firmware and reboot?

Comment: Yes, I installed a newer version and it seems to me wifi works more stable. Thanks to you, it is really helpful. I am not sure if it will help with `ACPI` error, but I used an `acpi_os=Windows noapic` linux kernel boot flag. ThinkPad S440 is made with Windows8+ in mind, so I suppose it could help somehow. As I see, there are lots of errors. How do you think on asking somebody on some special forum (don't know yet which one)?

Comment: I suggest you simply ask a new question here on askubuntu. I doubt you need those boot parameters, but that is not my specialty. I run  a Lenovo T410i and added nothing special to GRUB.