# Intel wireless 7260 driver crashes, how do I work around it?

Tags: wireless, drivers, intel-wireless

I'm having problems with the Wifi on my Xubuntu 13.10 and my new Lenovo X240 laptop. Sometimes the driver crashes.

```
lspci|grep -i wi

03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 83)


dmesg
[ 7522.845255] WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 842 at /build/buildd/linux-3.11.0/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/phy-ctxt.c:208 iwl_mvm_phy_ctxt_add+0x44/0x80 [iwlmvm]()
[ 7522.845259] Modules linked in: dm_crypt pci_stub vboxpci(OF) vboxnetadp(OF) vboxnetflt(OF) vboxdrv(OF) joydev parport_pc ppdev rfcomm bnep bluetooth arc4 x86_pkg_temp_thermal coretemp kvm_intel kvm crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd binfmt_misc uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_core videodev snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_hdmi nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hwdep ext2 microcode snd_pcm snd_page_alloc snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi psmouse serio_raw iwlmvm mac80211 thinkpad_acpi snd_seq nvram snd_seq_device tpm_tis snd_timer iwlwifi snd cfg80211 lpc_ich mei_me mei soundcore lp parport mac_hid intel_smartconnect hid_generic usbhid hid i915 i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper e1000e drm ahci ptp libahci pps_core wmi video
[ 7522.845364] CPU: 1 PID: 842 Comm: NetworkManager Tainted: GF       W  O 3.11.0-15-generic #23-Ubuntu
[ 7522.845368] Hardware name: LENOVO 20ALCTO1WW/20ALCTO1WW, BIOS GIET62WW (2.12 ) 09/25/2013
[ 7522.845371]  0000000000000009 ffff880210751620 ffffffff816e7335 0000000000000000
[ 7522.845379]  ffff880210751658 ffffffff81061dcd ffff88020c443b68 ffff88020c4437b0
[ 7522.845385]  0000000000000000 ffff88020c443b68 ffff88020c443b98 ffff880210751668
[ 7522.845392] Call Trace:
[ 7522.845405]  [<ffffffff816e7335>] dump_stack+0x45/0x56
[ 7522.845415]  [<ffffffff81061dcd>] warn_slowpath_common+0x7d/0xa0
[ 7522.845422]  [<ffffffff81061eaa>] warn_slowpath_null+0x1a/0x20
[ 7522.845437]  [<ffffffffa03bb3a4>] iwl_mvm_phy_ctxt_add+0x44/0x80 [iwlmvm]
[ 7522.845450]  [<ffffffffa03b79c7>] iwl_mvm_up+0x237/0x270 [iwlmvm]
[ 7522.845463]  [<ffffffffa03b9917>] iwl_mvm_mac_start+0x37/0x220 [iwlmvm]
[ 7522.845494]  [<ffffffffa030d00c>] ieee80211_do_open+0x43c/0xd80 [mac80211]
[ 7522.845518]  [<ffffffffa030a90b>] ? ieee80211_check_concurrent_iface+0x1b/0x1b0 [mac80211]
[ 7522.845544]  [<ffffffffa030d9b9>] ieee80211_open+0x69/0x70 [mac80211]
[ 7522.845551]  [<ffffffff815f2aef>] __dev_open+0xbf/0x140
[ 7522.845557]  [<ffffffff815f2db2>] __dev_change_flags+0x92/0x170
[ 7522.845564]  [<ffffffff815f2f3d>] dev_change_flags+0x1d/0x60
[ 7522.845570]  [<ffffffff81600412>] do_setlink+0x332/0x9f0
[ 7522.845579]  [<ffffffff81097355>] ? sched_clock_cpu+0xb5/0x100
[ 7522.845590]  [<ffffffff811d803f>] ? __find_get_block+0xbf/0x230
[ 7522.845598]  [<ffffffff8137df52>] ? nla_parse+0x32/0xe0
[ 7522.845604]  [<ffffffff81601734>] rtnl_newlink+0x394/0x5e0
[ 7522.845613]  [<ffffffff81318aa4>] ? apparmor_capable+0x24/0x180
[ 7522.845621]  [<ffffffff815fe159>] rtnetlink_rcv_msg+0x99/0x260
[ 7522.845628]  [<ffffffff81190ba8>] ? __kmalloc_node_track_caller+0x58/0x1d0
[ 7522.845634]  [<ffffffff815e179e>] ? __alloc_skb+0x7e/0x2b0
[ 7522.845642]  [<ffffffff815fe0c0>] ? rtnetlink_rcv+0x30/0x30
[ 7522.845648]  [<ffffffff8161c069>] netlink_rcv_skb+0xa9/0xc0
[ 7522.845655]  [<ffffffff815fe0b8>] rtnetlink_rcv+0x28/0x30
[ 7522.845660]  [<ffffffff8161b6bd>] netlink_unicast+0xdd/0x190
[ 7522.845668]  [<ffffffff8136eaad>] ? memcpy_fromiovec+0x4d/0x90
[ 7522.845673]  [<ffffffff8161ba6f>] netlink_sendmsg+0x2ff/0x740
[ 7522.845682]  [<ffffffff8161878c>] ? netlink_rcv_wake+0x3c/0x50
[ 7522.845687]  [<ffffffff81619aa5>] ? netlink_recvmsg+0x205/0x390
[ 7522.845695]  [<ffffffff815d92a9>] sock_sendmsg+0x99/0xd0
[ 7522.845701]  [<ffffffff815d9968>] ? sock_recvmsg+0xa8/0xe0
[ 7522.845747]  [<ffffffff81685e2c>] ? unix_dgram_sendmsg+0x59c/0x600
[ 7522.845758]  [<ffffffff815d96e8>] ___sys_sendmsg+0x3b8/0x3d0
[ 7522.845791]  [<ffffffff815d987e>] ? SYSC_sendto+0x17e/0x1c0
[ 7522.845826]  [<ffffffff815da4e2>] __sys_sendmsg+0x42/0x80
[ 7522.845852]  [<ffffffff815da532>] SyS_sendmsg+0x12/0x20
[ 7522.845878]  [<ffffffff816f721d>] system_call_fastpath+0x1a/0x1f
```

Sometimes I just get errors

```
[ 7581.808662] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Microcode SW error detected.  Restarting 0x2000000.
[ 7581.808674] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: CSR values:
[ 7581.808679] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: (2nd byte of CSR_INT_COALESCING is CSR_INT_PERIODIC_REG)
[ 7581.808782] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0:        CSR_HW_IF_CONFIG_REG: 0X00489204
[ 7581.808840] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0:          CSR_INT_COALESCING: 0X00000040
[ 7581.808897] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0:                     CSR_INT: 0X00000000
[ 7581.808953] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0:                CSR_INT_MASK: 0X00000000
[ 7581.809010] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0:           CSR_FH_INT_STATUS: 0X00000000
[ 7581.809066] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0:                 CSR_GPIO_IN: 0X00000000
[ 7581.809121] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0:                   CSR_RESET: 0X00000000
[ 7581.809176] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0:                CSR_GP_CNTRL: 0X080403c5
[ 7581.809233] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0:                  CSR_HW_REV: 0X00000144
[ 7581.809289] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0:              CSR_EEPROM_REG: 0X00000000
[ 7581.809344] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0:               CSR_EEPROM_GP: 0X80000000
[ 7581.809400] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0:              CSR_OTP_GP_REG: 0X803a0000
[ 7581.809456] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0:                 CSR_GIO_REG: 0X00080042
[ 7581.809534] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0:            CSR_GP_UCODE_REG: 0X00000000
[ 7581.809684] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0:           CSR_GP_DRIVER_REG: 0X00000000
[ 7581.809743] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0:           CSR_UCODE_DRV_GP1: 0X00000000
[ 7581.809894] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0:           CSR_UCODE_DRV_GP2: 0X00000000
[ 7581.809953] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0:                 CSR_LED_REG: 0X00000060
[ 7581.810013] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0:        CSR_DRAM_INT_TBL_REG: 0X88211595
[ 7581.810164] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0:        CSR_GIO_CHICKEN_BITS: 0X27800200
[ 7581.810223] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0:             CSR_ANA_PLL_CFG: 0Xd55555d5
[ 7581.810375] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0:           CSR_HW_REV_WA_REG: 0X0001001a
[ 7581.810526] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0:        CSR_DBG_HPET_MEM_REG: 0Xffff0010
[ 7581.810533] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: FH register values:
[ 7581.810694] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0:         FH_RSCSR_CHNL0_STTS_WPTR_REG: 0X2118f900
[ 7581.810762] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0:        FH_RSCSR_CHNL0_RBDCB_BASE_REG: 0X02118f80
[ 7581.810831] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0:                  FH_RSCSR_CHNL0_WPTR: 0X000000f0
[ 7581.810900] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0:         FH_MEM_RCSR_CHNL0_CONFIG_REG: 0X00801114
[ 7581.810968] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0:          FH_MEM_RSSR_SHARED_CTRL_REG: 0X000000fc
[ 7581.811033] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0:            FH_MEM_RSSR_RX_STATUS_REG: 0X03230000
[ 7581.811099] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0:    FH_MEM_RSSR_RX_ENABLE_ERR_IRQ2DRV: 0X00000000
[ 7581.811165] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0:                FH_TSSR_TX_STATUS_REG: 0X07ff0001
[ 7581.811231] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0:                 FH_TSSR_TX_ERROR_REG: 0X00000000
[ 7581.811394] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[ 7581.811399] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Status: 0x00000000, count: 6
[ 7581.811404] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x0000003C | NMI_INTERRUPT_DATA_ACTION_PT
[ 7581.811407] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000230 | uPc
[ 7581.811411] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | branchlink1
[ 7581.811415] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000C8A | branchlink2
[ 7581.811418] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00014078 | interruptlink1
[ 7581.811422] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000676 | interruptlink2
[ 7581.811426] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000D40 | data1
[ 7581.811429] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000008 | data2
[ 7581.811433] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x03230000 | data3
[ 7581.811436] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x66418352 | beacon time
[ 7581.811440] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x9C09287A | tsf low
[ 7581.811444] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000023 | tsf hi
[ 7581.811447] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[ 7581.811451] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x03844AFE | time gp2
[ 7581.811454] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp3
[ 7581.811458] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00321600 | uCode version
[ 7581.811462] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000144 | hw version
[ 7581.811465] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00489204 | board version
[ 7581.811469] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x0000001C | hcmd
[ 7581.811473] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xA6F62000 | isr0
[ 7581.811476] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x01004000 | isr1
[ 7581.811480] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000002 | isr2
[ 7581.811483] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x0041FC85 | isr3
[ 7581.811487] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr4
[ 7581.811490] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x10000112 | isr_pref
[ 7581.811494] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000D40 | wait_event
[ 7581.811497] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x000000D0 | l2p_control
[ 7581.811501] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00010030 | l2p_duration
[ 7581.811505] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x0000003F | l2p_mhvalid
[ 7581.811508] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x000000CE | l2p_addr_match
[ 7581.811512] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000007 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[ 7581.811516] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x63E8869E | timestamp
[ 7581.811519] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x0034F000 | flow_handler
[ 7581.811526] ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested
[ 7581.812863] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled; Disabling L0S
[ 7581.813342] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled; Disabling L0S
```

I'm using the latest Xubuntu kernel

```
3.11.0-15-generic #23-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 9 18:17:04 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a newer firmware file that is supposed to cure some instability. Please open a terminal and back up your current firmware:

```
cd /lib/firmware
sudo mv iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode  iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode.bak
```

Now download the newer firmware:

```
sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode
```

Now unload and reload the driver so it sees the new firmware:

(Note that the `iwlwifi` module loads either the `iwldvm` or `iwlmvm` module depending on the system, so you'll have to remove the correct one before you're able to remove `iwlwifi`. I've used `iwldvm` here, but you should use `iwlmvm` if you get no results from the command `lsmod | grep iwldvm`.)

```
sudo modprobe -r iwldvm
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

There is no need to run `sudo modprobe iwl?vm` because `iwlwifi` will take care of that automatically.

See also:

- http://marc.info/?l=linux-wireless&m=138718659005765&w=2
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1305305
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/intel/+bug/1265436

Comment: I don't have the `iwldvm` module loaded.

Comment: @Bepetersn I suggest you reboot. If that doesn't fix it,  please start your own new question.

Comment: I need to download the firmware from another OS but I just get an HTML page... Where can i get the new firmware for Intel Wireless 7260?
`wget https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/egrumbach/linux-firmware.git/plain/iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode`

Comment: @dotnetCarpenter Here: http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi#Firmware Once on the Ubuntu machine, right-click to extract and move to /lib/firmware.

Comment: @chili555 thanks. I've downloaded for kernel 3.13+, used `diff` and the firmware that I already have is identical. How can I check that it is in fact used by ubuntu?

Comment: Hmm.. I just did the `modprobe` three-liner and I still can not connect to the wifi. It seems to be another issue.

Comment: @dotnetCarpenter Start a new question and add all the details you can and I'll help.

Comment: thanks @chili555 - I posted a question here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/573056/intel-dual-band-wireless-7260-can-not-connect