# Intel wireless 7260 (rev 73) / NUC N2820: OK during install, failed after install

Tags: wireless, intel

I have a new mini-PC Intel NUC N2820 and it has a fairly new wireless controller Intel 7260 (rev 73).

I downloaded the source, compiled and installed it.

But the problem is that during the installation I connected to wireless (in the beginning), entered the password for the wifi, and it even updated during the installation, but failed after the install was complete.

Answer (score 1):

Is the driver loading? Check from the terminal:

```
lsmod | grep iwl
```

If not, load it and see if the problem is fixed:

```
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

If that fixes it, let's get *iwlwifi* to load on boot.

```
sudo -i
echo iwlwifi >> /etc/modules
exit
```

Do you have the latest firmware?

```
ls -al /lib/firmware | grep 7260
```

The newest is 683236 iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode; the older is smaller,  682892. If you have the older firmware, update it: [Intel wireless 7260 driver crashes, how do I work around it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/411475/intel-wireless-7260-driver-crashes-how-do-i-work-around-it/411515#411515)

Finally, look for clues:

```
dmesg | grep iwl
```

Comment: Hi, this is what I am getting from the dmesg

[    2.503391] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.509706] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[    2.509856] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: irq 107 for MSI/MSI-X
[    2.853943] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: request for firmware file 'iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode' failed.
[    2.853946] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: no suitable firmware found!

Comment: You have no firmware file at all. Please retrace the process in the link I gave to install it.

Comment: Yeah, I will and thank you for that. But that requires me to have internet access somehow. I'll use the ethernet port to get connected to internet and do just that or compile it myself. My question is, how is it that I use the wireless during the installation and can't after?

Comment: I haven't any idea why it works _at all_ in the USB! There is nothing to compile; simply download the proper firmware in the proper location and reboot. If ethernet access is a problem, I can edit my question to show how to download it on some other computer and transfer it on a USB. Is that what you'd prefer?

Comment: Anyway, after getting the internet working with a usb wifi stick, update solved the driver problem. Thanks for the help.

Comment: So if the problem is solved, are you ready to accept my answer?

Comment: I do but since I couldn't install the driver using the instructions in that link maybe I shouldn't check it because it may direct people in the wrong direction. What do you suggest?

Comment: It's entirely your decision. If your wireless is working, I'm happy.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem on a Toshiba Portege R30 (with intel wireless 7260, hence requiring the iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode firmware file).

Symptoms: Wifi ok during install of Ubuntu 12.4 from USB stick (alongside and already installed Windows 8.1), but afterwards, when using the installed Ubuntu, no Wifi servers were detected, and hence no wireless internet was available.

```
lsmod | grep iwl
```

showed that the firmware file was not there while:

```
dmesg | grep iwl
```

showed also an error message that the firmware could not be found.

I downloaded the required firmware via:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmare
```

after which the required firmware file "iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode" was now present in: /lib/firmware

Rebooted and the Wifi worked fine.