# Wireless issue on Lenovo Thinkpad L540

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, thinkpad, intel-wireless

I recently installed Ubuntu 13.10 on my Lenovo Thinkpad L540. It has problem with the wifi connection. When just booted it works then suddenly it drops the connection and cannot even see the wifi networks.

- I tried to install the windows driver for the wireless card Intel 7260 but I'm not able to extract the .inf file from the .exe that I download from Intel website. With the .inf file I should then be able to install the driver using ndiswrapper but, since I cannot get the .inf file, this way is gone.
- I tried also following other ways. I upgraded the Kernel to the 3.13 from 3.11 but still it doesn't work.
- I tried also to follow instructions such as those from [Intel wireless 7260 driver crashes, how do I work around it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/411475/intel-wireless-7260-driver-crashes-how-do-i-work-around-it) but every time I give the command `sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi` I get:

  > FATAL: Module iwlwifi is in use.

6-April-EDIT:

- The command `sudo modprobe -rf iwlmvm` before `sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi`, doesn't change the situationi. Still the output to the second command is

  > FATAL: Module iwlwifi is in use.
- The output to `uname -r` is

  > 3.13.1-031301-generic
- The output to `dmesg | grep iwl` is a long list made of elements like the following

  > [ 2028.111303] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled; Disabling L0S

  plus some few exception lines which give

  > [ 2031.232825] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to enable radio.

Comment: Please try: sudo modprobe -rf iwlmvm. It will take iwlwifi away with it. Please edit your post to include: dmesg | grep iwl and also: uname -r Thanks.

Comment: @chili555 : I also tried your own answer from http://askubuntu.com/questions/331667/no-wireless-for-intel-corporation-7260-version-63/331696#331696 , but still I wasn't lucky.

Comment: We need to see that long list of elements in order to diagnose what's going wrong. Please run: dmesg | grep iwl > wifi.txt and also: lspci -nn >> wifi.txt. Find the file wifi.txt in your user directory and paste it here: http://paste.ubuntu.com Give us the link in your reply.

Answer (score 0):

I have a different laptop, but the same card and the same problem. The network connection fails after about 5 minutes. You can temporarily restart it by disabling then re-enabling wifi. Then after another 5 minutes it fails again.

Look in /var/log/syslog to see if you have an error like this:

```
WARNING: CPU: 3 PID: 76 at /build/buildd/linux-3.11.0/net/mac80211/util.c:1538
```

followed by a stack trace. There appears to be a bug in the Intel 7260 driver that causes the network connection to crash, although it still says it is up. The cure is to upgrade the kernel, but via an upgrade to the operating system. I upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 and my kernel is now `3.13.0-24-generic` and the problem has gone away.
Ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04 upgrade instructions are here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/upgrade

If your network connection fails after 5 minutes as mine does it may take quite a few goes before you download all of the necessary files. But keep repeating the instructions you find there until it works.

Comment: I upgraded to 14.04 and nothing improved. I also tried with a fresh ubuntu 14.04 install, and still the wifi connection fails after few minutes. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Is it possible to change the wifi card in a Laptop? which one should I go for in case?

Answer (score 0):

Just wanna throw this out there.
I have a Lenovo B50-70 and wireless crashed all the time. It was active for a while on a fresh boot-up, and it just timedout after about 10 - 15 minutes or less.

What worked for me, was:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge avahi-daemon resolvconf
```

You can also add new nameservers in your /etc/resolv.conf

```
$ sudo vi /etc/resolv.conf
```

Add these lines:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
name server 8.8.4.4
```

Comment: Thanks god with Ubuntu 14.10 it started working properly. It was very annoying. If the problem presents itself again I'll give it a try. Thanks.