# Intel Wireless 7260 card doesn't connect to WiFi sometimes

Tags: wireless, networking, intel-wireless

(Also [posted in Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/29dn70/i_posted_a_problem_i_have_with_my_wifi_and/))

I have a strange problem. My machine sometimes (more often no than yes) doesn't connect to my home wifi. I can connect to android devices hot spot easily. Windows machine connects as well. Finally, I can use my android devices as a usb wifi card.
I know I should put some data here, I don't what technical data I should put, but here are some anecdotes:

1. Currently, my home network doesn't have a password, or spaces in its name.
2. From my experience, if I wait long enough (like an hour) the chances are it will connect are higher.
3. This might be a coincidental, but often, the machine connects right after I plug my phone as WiFi card.
4. I have two Lenovo machines (Edge 13 and ideapad u330p) both doesn't connect. The Edge machine currently runs Arch, but Ubuntu didn't connect with it as well. Interestingly, live USB of Lubuntu connected on the edge machine.

I'm more concerned about the ideapad machine as the edge machine is soon to turn into a stationary machine that connects via cable.
So, how do I avoid/handle the mishaps?

#### Things I have tried:

- [Updating the Intel firmware](https://askubuntu.com/questions/411475/intel-wireless-7260-driver-crashes-how-do-i-work-around-it) - It still doesn't connect. I note that to stop `iwlwifi` I have to stop both `iwlmvm` and `iwldvm`.

Here is the output of the linked script. I'm at the campus right now, so things might not seem exactly as I described them. To my understanding, the issue is with network card (intel 7260) which has new firmware available, only I didn't find anyway to activate it.

```
########## wireless info START ##########

##### release #####

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel #####

Linux twisting 3.13.0-30-generic #54-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 9 22:45:01 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

##### lspci #####

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b2] (rev 73)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless-N 7260 [8086:4262]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

##### lsusb #####

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:572a Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 1058:070a Western Digital Technologies, Inc. My Passport Essential SE
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 18d1:4ee4 Google Inc. Nexus 4 (debug + tether)
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 045e:009d Microsoft Corp. Wireless Optical Desktop 3.0
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0424:2514 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA Card Info #####

##### rfkill #####

0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #####

iwlmvm                189774  0 
mac80211              626557  1 iwlmvm
iwlwifi               169932  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211              484040  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwlmvm

##### iw reg get #####

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS

##### interfaces #####

# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### iwconfig #####

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on


##### route #####

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.42.129  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 usb0
192.168.42.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 usb0

##### resolv.conf #####

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### nm-tool #####

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: wlan0 ----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            iwlwifi
  State:             disconnected
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC address removed>

  Capabilities:

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points 

- Device: usb0  [Wired connection 1] -------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            rndis_host
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC address removed>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.42.185
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.42.129

    DNS:             192.168.42.129

##### NetworkManager.state #####

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf #####

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### iwlist #####

wlan0     No scan results

##### iwlist channel #####

wlan0     13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz

##### modinfo #####

filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-30-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/iwlmvm.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003-2013 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
version:        in-tree:
description:    The new Intel(R) wireless AGN driver for Linux
srcversion:     964B69F7EBC572BE39F5C50
depends:        iwlwifi,mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-30-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        <MAC address removed>:20:E4:8D:AC:C7:DB:4A:17:03:31:CC:24:8D:65
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           init_dbg:set to true to debug an ASSERT in INIT fw (default: false (bool)
parm:           power_scheme:power management scheme: 1-active, 2-balanced, 3-low power, default: 2 (int)

filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-30-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003-2013 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
version:        in-tree:
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-7.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode
srcversion:     1E6912E109D5A43B310FB34
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005490bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Bsv*sd00005290bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005590bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005190bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005090bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005420bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd0000502Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005020bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00009410bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00009310bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00009510bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00009210bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00009112bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00009110bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00009012bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00009010bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Bsv*sd00005202bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005002bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Bsv*sd00005200bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd0000500Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005000bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00001010bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005400bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005410bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005012bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Bsv*sd00005210bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Bsv*sd00005302bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Bsv*sd00005310bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd0000510Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005100bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005112bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005110bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005010bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00008570bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00008470bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B4sv*sd00008270bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00008062bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00008060bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00008172bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00008170bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00008072bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00008070bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B4sv*sd00000370bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00000472bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00000470bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B4sv*sd00000272bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B4sv*sd00000270bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00000062bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00000060bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00000172bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00000170bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00000072bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00000070bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C420bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd0000C220bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C02Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C020bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C360bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd0000C370bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C560bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C570bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C462bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C460bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C472bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C470bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd0000C262bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd0000C26Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd0000C260bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd0000C272bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd0000C270bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C760bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C770bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C162bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C062bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C160bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C06Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C060bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C170bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C072bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C070bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004420bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd00004220bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000402Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004020bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00005070bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd00004360bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd00004370bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004560bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004570bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004A6Cbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004A6Ebc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004A70bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000486Ebc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004870bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004462bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000446Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004460bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004472bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004470bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd00004262bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd0000426Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd00004260bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd00004272bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd00004270bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004162bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004062bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004160bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000406Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004060bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004170bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004072bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004070bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000892sv*sd00000462bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000893sv*sd00000262bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000892sv*sd00000062bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000894sv*sd00000822bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000894sv*sd00000422bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000895sv*sd00000222bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000894sv*sd00000022bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000088Fsv*sd00005260bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000088Esv*sd00004860bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000088Esv*sd0000446Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000088Esv*sd00004460bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000088Fsv*sd0000426Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000088Fsv*sd00004260bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000088Esv*sd0000406Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000088Esv*sd00004060bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000887sv*sd00004462bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000888sv*sd00004262bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000887sv*sd00004062bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000890sv*sd00004822bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000890sv*sd00004422bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000891sv*sd00004222bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000890sv*sd00004022bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000896sv*sd00005027bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000896sv*sd00005025bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000897sv*sd00005017bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000897sv*sd00005015bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000896sv*sd00005007bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000896sv*sd00005005bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008AEsv*sd00001027bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008AEsv*sd00001025bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008AFsv*sd00001017bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008AFsv*sd00001015bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008AEsv*sd00001007bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008AEsv*sd00001005bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000084sv*sd00001316bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000084sv*sd00001216bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000083sv*sd00001326bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000083sv*sd00001226bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000083sv*sd00001306bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000083sv*sd00001206bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000084sv*sd00001315bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000084sv*sd00001215bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000083sv*sd00001325bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000083sv*sd00001225bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000083sv*sd00001305bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000083sv*sd00001205bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000886sv*sd00001317bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000886sv*sd00001315bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000885sv*sd00001327bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000885sv*sd00001325bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000885sv*sd00001307bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000885sv*sd00001305bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000089sv*sd00001316bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000089sv*sd00001311bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000087sv*sd00001326bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000087sv*sd00001321bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000087sv*sd00001306bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000087sv*sd00001301bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000091sv*sd00005226bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000091sv*sd00005225bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000091sv*sd00005221bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000091sv*sd00005207bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000091sv*sd00005206bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000091sv*sd00005205bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000091sv*sd00005201bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000090sv*sd00005216bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000090sv*sd00005215bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000090sv*sd00005211bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000008Bsv*sd00005317bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000008Bsv*sd00005315bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000008Asv*sd00005327bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000008Asv*sd00005325bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000008Asv*sd00005307bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000008Asv*sd00005305bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001305bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001304bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00004820bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000085sv*sd0000C228bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000085sv*sd0000C220bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd0000C020bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000085sv*sd00001316bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000085sv*sd00001318bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000085sv*sd00001311bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001328bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001326bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001321bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001308bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001307bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001306bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001301bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004239sv*sd00001316bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004239sv*sd00001311bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004238sv*sd00001118bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004238sv*sd00001111bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Csv*sd00001326bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Csv*sd00001321bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Csv*sd00001307bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Csv*sd00001306bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Csv*sd00001301bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Bsv*sd00001128bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Bsv*sd00001121bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Bsv*sd00001108bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Bsv*sd00001101bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Dsv*sd00001316bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Dsv*sd00001216bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Dsv*sd00001311bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Dsv*sd00001211bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Csv*sd00001326bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Csv*sd00001321bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Csv*sd00001221bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Csv*sd00001306bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Csv*sd00001206bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Csv*sd00001301bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Csv*sd00001201bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Bsv*sd00001011bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Asv*sd00001021bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Asv*sd00001001bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004236sv*sd00001114bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004236sv*sd00001014bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004236sv*sd00001111bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004236sv*sd00001011bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004235sv*sd00001104bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004235sv*sd00001004bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004235sv*sd00001101bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004235sv*sd00001001bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004235sv*sd00001124bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004235sv*sd00001024bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004235sv*sd00001121bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004235sv*sd00001021bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004237sv*sd00001316bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004237sv*sd00001216bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004237sv*sd00001315bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004237sv*sd00001215bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004237sv*sd00001314bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004237sv*sd00001214bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004237sv*sd00001311bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004237sv*sd00001211bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001326bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001226bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001325bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001225bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001324bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001224bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001321bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001221bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001306bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001206bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001305bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001205bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001304bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001204bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001301bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001201bc*sc*i*
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-30-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        <MAC address removed>:20:E4:8D:AC:C7:DB:4A:17:03:31:CC:24:8D:65
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size_8K:enable 8K amsdu size (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (defualt: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           wd_disable:Disable stuck queue watchdog timer 0=system default, 1=disable, 2=enable (default: 0) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)

##### modules #####

lp
rtc

##### blacklist #####

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/fbdev-blacklist.conf]
blacklist arkfb
blacklist aty128fb
blacklist atyfb
blacklist radeonfb
blacklist cirrusfb
blacklist cyber2000fb
blacklist gx1fb
blacklist gxfb
blacklist kyrofb
blacklist matroxfb_base
blacklist mb862xxfb
blacklist neofb
blacklist nvidiafb
blacklist pm2fb
blacklist pm3fb
blacklist s3fb
blacklist savagefb
blacklist sisfb
blacklist tdfxfb
blacklist tridentfb
blacklist viafb
blacklist vt8623fb

##### udev rules #####

# PCI device 0x8086:0x08b2 (iwlwifi)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address removed>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #####

[    1.694403] psmouse serio1: elantech: assuming hardware version 4 (with firmware version 0x461f01)
[    5.421902] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: irq 62 for MSI/MSI-X
[    5.503332] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load failed with error -2
[    5.503333] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Falling back to user helper
[    5.521430] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.2.3.d.bseq
[    5.624522] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware patch completed and activated
[    5.927671] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 22.1.7.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    6.534354] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wireless N 7260, REV=0x144
[    6.534403] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
[    6.534616] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
[    6.770451] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[   12.058643] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
[   12.058857] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
[   12.070328] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   12.070662] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: Please run the script that is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Comment: This appears to be a bug in the intel firmware: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1305305

Comment: Ok, can you try this one and see if it works? http://askubuntu.com/questions/411475/intel-wireless-7260-driver-crashes-how-do-i-work-around-it

Comment: Also according to launchpad the newest firmware is shipped in 14.04 as an update, you might want to doublecheck that all updates are installed.

Comment: @JorgeCastro, Nope, it still doesn't connect. I note that to stop ``iwlwifi`` I have to stop both ``iwlmvm`` and ``iwldvm``.

Comment: @JorgeCastro. I have just downloaded Ubuntu 14.10, the Kylin version, for a test. The wifi seems to work properly there (tested for about 5 minutes). Also, after the reboot. I've managed to connect to my home network. But I didn't manage to browse anywhere. Pinging my router resulted with 100% package loss (6 attempts)

Answer (score 4):

After have wireless issues myself with my Intel wireless card I researched a bit and found a few commmon attempts to fix it. I've done these myself and have much better stability on my laptop.

I don't recall the exact site I followed, but a quick google search jogged my memory and these are the two things I did ( from http://itsfoss.com/speed-up-slow-wifi-connection-ubuntu/ )

1) Disable 802.11n

```
sudo rmmod iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

That will make the change until the next reboot. Test it and see if you have a more stable connection to your wireless AP. If so, you can make it permanent by doing the following (you can always revert this change by editing that file and removing the line it adds)

```
sudo su
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" >> /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

2) Disable wireless card power features

```
sudo iwconfig
```

It will give you the name of your wireless device. Normally it should be wlan0. Now use the following command:

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

Comment: With switching the power off, the connection is more stable. I manage to browse the web, but from time to time the connection is non responsive. Pinging Google ended with 5% package loss.

Comment: Also, my network is at b mode only. How can I apply this to my machine?

Comment: Your wireless AP is only b? You should still be able to do the disable n option, as that is client side and maybe it's trying to find a N network and getting fouled up.

Comment: didn't work for me this solution with lenovo t440p same wifi card

Comment: I believe 802.11n is broken in Ubuntu. $ sudo vim /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
and append to bottom:
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing similar problem with my Intel 3160ac. Using wavemon I found out that the number of retries is huge and that it probably that cause of the frequent disconnections.
Follow also what  tgm4883 said, but add:

> `$echo "options iwlmvm power_scheme=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlmvm.conf`
>   `$echo "options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=N swcrypto=1 11n_disable=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`
>   `$sudo reboot`

If the problem is not solved, I suggest to look at this bug report:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1354975

essentially install  the Kernel 3.13.0-37_3.13.0-37.64+iwlltr0001 from: http://people.canonical.com/~sforshee/iwl-ltr/trusty/

and also install the linux-firmware 1.127.7.

Then if it does not work, you can try again the command I wrote above.

Comment: didn't work for me this solution with lenovo t440p same wifi card