# Ubuntu 16 LTS Connection to wifi suddenly extremely slow (Wireless 7260)

Tags: networking, drivers, 16.04, intel-wireless

After having to force power off my laptop, I can't seem to do anything with wifi anymore on Ubuntu. I have my laptop dual booted with Windows 8 and Ubuntu, Windows 8 can't seem to even connect to wifi while Ubuntu can connect, but cannot load anything at all. After about 20 minutes of loading a webpage it receives about 200kiB. I have had this setup for about a month now and had no problems with wifi until now. I've been using a USB wifi adapter and that makes wifi work fine but I'd really like to fix my laptop.

I tried using this solution: [Intel Wireless 7260 card doesn't connect to WiFi sometimes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/489157/intel-wireless-7260-card-doesnt-connect-to-wifi-sometimes)

Even tried setting 11n_disable=8 but still nothing.

Are there any tools I could use to diagnose this problem further or any other possible solutions to this?

output from dmesg | grep iwl

```
[   11.288209] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode failed with error -2
[   11.505438] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 16.242414.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[   12.347174] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7260, REV=0x144
[   12.347513] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   12.348017] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   12.627245] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[   12.659054] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[   34.186316] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   34.186976] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   34.380035] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   34.380672] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   38.722966] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: No association and the time event is over already...
[   42.303018] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: No association and the time event is over already...
[   45.872402] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: No association and the time event is over already...
[   49.456533] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: No association and the time event is over already...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest firmware package contains the -17 firmware; your device loads -16. Let's try installing it:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.161_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

Next, check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit.

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Next, I'd set IPv6 to Ignore in Network Manager: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/Installation_Guide/images/netconfig/network-connections-ipv6-ignore.png  This example is for ethernet, but you want wireless.

Reboot and tell us if the connectivity is improved.

You might also try a couple of driver parameters:

```
sudo -i
echo "options iwlwifi swcrypto=1 11n_disable=8"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
exit
```

Reboot. Can you connect?

Comment: Updated firmware, changed region (sudo iw reg get now returns US), and ignored IPv6, but no change. I'm getting this from "dmesg | grep iwl": "iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: No association and the time event is over already...". Is there anything else I could try?

Comment: Are you able to try any of the changes at the router that I suggested? Also, please see my edit above.

Comment: Yes! After router reboot it worked. Thank you!