# Linux firmware management not clear

Tags: 14.04, intel-wireless, firmware, iwlwifi

I have a laptop with *Intel Wireless 7260* on the board and had some problems with connection in Ubuntu 14.04 (3.13.0-36-generic). While solving this I was required to update firmware called `iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode` for the `iwlwifi` module as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/411515/275017). But I discovered that there is another newer(?) firmware issued by Intel: [`iwlwifi-7260-9.ucode`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/egrumbach/linux-firmware.git/plain/) so I decided to use it instead of *-7 version, removed the *-7 from `/lib/firmware/`, downloaded *-9, restarted the `iwlwifi` and was happily left without networking support. Now I discovered that `iwlwifi` uses *-7 version only and there is nothing about *-8 and *-9:

```
modinfo iwlwifi
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-36-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003-2013 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
version:        in-tree:
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
...
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode
...
```

**So my question is:** am I getting something wrong and *-9 is not an firmware version, or I should search (or recompile) `iwlwifi` to work with newer modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of the firmware you're using is actually dependent on the version of the driver in the kernel. So while -9 isn't a firmware version, per se, it does correspond with a driver in a later kernel. (In other words, just use the firmware version that corresponds with your kernel version, eh!)

For more info, see: http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi#Firmware