# Ubuntu 12.04 NO network devices available

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking

I've just installed 12.04 in a dual boot with Windows 8 via a USB. The important point is that **my laptop doesn't have an Ethernet**. When I booted to the USB,  wireless networking worked. Now that I've installed 12.04 on a partition on the hard drive I can't get wireless networking to work.

Any suggestions on how I should  fix this?

The output of `sudo lshw -C network` is:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Network controller
   product: Wireless 7260
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   version: 6b
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:b2500000-b2501fff
```

Comment: The driver and firmware for the Intel 7260 don't exist in most versions of 12.04. It will be very, very difficult to download on a USB all the packages and their dependencies. The device works out of the box with a simple firmware download in 13.10. I suggest you re-install.

Comment: Thank you chilli555 but apparently I didn't need a re-install because I found my answer here whose author is you :) http://askubuntu.com/questions/331667/no-wireless-for-intel-corporation-7260-version-63