# Intel 7260 works during installation but not after reboot

Tags: wireless, drivers, 13.10, intel-wireless, iwlwifi

Before you hit dupe: I've already attempted the steps listed in [No wireless for Intel Corporation 7260 version 63](https://askubuntu.com/questions/331667/no-wireless-for-intel-corporation-7260-version-63) question.  I have the proper microcode loaded into `/lib/firmware` and I'm running kernel version 3.11.

I'm having some issues with a completely fresh install of Kubuntu 13.10: my wireless card works on the live USB (created with unetbootin) but on the installed system the driver fails to load and gives a backtrace with error failed to probe (hw address?) with error -12. Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions? Google is coming up dry.

From `kern.log` (10 finger interface, so some information omitted):

```
---[ cut here]---
WARNING CPU: 10 PID: 302 at /build/buildd/linux-3.11.0/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/pcie/rc.x:1059 iwl_pcie_alloc_ict+0x1cb/0x210 [iwlwifi]()
Modules linked in: iwlwifi(+) parport_pc psmouse cfg80211 ppdev serio_raw snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_intel(+) bnep rfcomm snd_hda_codec bluetooth snd_hwdep     lpc_ich snd_pcm snd_page_alloc snd_seq_midi (and many others)
CPU: 10 PID: 302 Comm: kworker/10:1 Tainted: GF 3.11.0-18-generic #32-Ubuntu
Hardware name: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. Z9PE-D8 WS/Z9PE-D8 WS, BIOS 5304 11/18/2013
Workqueue: events work_for_cpu_fn
(12 memory addresses here, 1st, 4th and 10th are very small, 4th is nil)
Call Trace:
[address] dump_stack+0x45/0x56
[address] warn_slowpath_common+0x7d/0xa0
[address] warn_slowpath_null+0x1a/0x20
[address] iwl_pcie_alloc_ict+0x1cb/0x210
[address] iwl_trans_pcie_alloc+0x26a/0x400
[address] iwl_pci_probe+0x1d/0xc0
(9 trace entries omitted)
---[ end trace (address) ]---
iwlwifi:probe of 0000:84:00.0 failed with error -12
```

`lspci`:

```
84:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 04)
```

`lsmod`:

```
iwlwifi   165636 0
cfg 80211 480503 1 iwlwifi
```

`dmesg | grep 84:00`

```
pci 0000:84:00.0: [8086:08b1] type 00 class 0x028000
pci 0000:84:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xfb100000-0xfb101fff 64bit]
pci 0000:84:00.0: PME# supportd from D0 D3hot D3cold
pci 0000:84:00.0: Signaling PME through PCIe PME interrupt
iwlwifi 0000:84:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
iwlwifi 0000:84:00.0: irq 133 for MSI/MSI-X
iwlwifi: probe of 0000:84:00.0 failed with error -12
```

`dmesg | grep iwl`

```
iwlwifi 0000:84:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
iwlwifi 0000:84:00.0: irq 133 for MSI/MSI-X
WARNING CPU: 10 PID: 302 at /build/buildd/linux-3.11.0/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/pcie/rc.x:1059 iwl_pcie_alloc_ict+0x1cb/0x210 [iwlwifi]()
Modules linked in: iwlwifi(+) parport_pc psmouse cfg80211 ppdev serio_raw snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_intel(+) bnep rfcomm snd_hda_codec bluetooth snd_hwdep     lpc_ich snd_pcm snd_page_alloc snd_seq_midi (and many others)
[address] iwl_pcie_alloc_ict+0x1cb/0x210
[address] iwl_trans_pcie_alloc+0x26a/0x400
[address] iwl_pci_probe+0x1d/0xc0
iwlwifi: probe of 0000:84:00.0 failed with error -12
```

`dmesg | grep -i error`

```
ioapic: probe of 0000:00:05.4 failed with error -22
ioapic: probe of 0000:80:05.4 failed with error -22
ERST: Error Record Serialization Table (ERST) support is initialized.
nouveau: probe of 0000:04:00.0 failed with error -22
nouveau: probe of 0000:83:00.0 failed with error -22
iwlwifi: probe of 0000:84:00.0 failed with error -12
EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
```

`lsmod | grep iwl`

```
iwlwifi 165636 0
cfg80211 480503 1 iwlwifi
```

Same command after `modprobe`ing iwlmvm:

```
iwlmvm 161339 0
mac80211 597268 1 iwlmvm
iwlwifi 165636 1 iwlmvm
cfg80211 480503 3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwlmvm
```

However, I still don't have `wlan0` if my `ifconfig` and `iwconfig` returns nothing interesting after modprobe

`cat /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` matches the version pasted in Chili555's answer below.

### Below this line are samples of it working within the installer.

`dmesg | grep iwl`

```
iwlwifi 0000:84:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
iwlwifi 0000:84:00.0: irq 132 for MSI/MSI-X
iwlwifi 0000:84:00.0: loaded firmware version 22.0.7.0 op_mode iwlmvm
iwlwifi 0000:84:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7260, REV=0x144
iwlwifi 0000:84:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
iwlwifi 0000:84:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
iwlwifi 0000:84:00.0: ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
iwlwifi 0000:84:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
iwlwifi 0000:84:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
```

`lspci | grep 84:00`:

```
84:00.0 Network controller: Intel corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 73)
```

(Detected different revision(?!))

Installer is using Kernel 3.11.0-12-generic, Installed system is running Kernel 3.11.0-18-generic

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: See my bug report and add some heat: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1305305

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I'd get a temporary wired ethernet connection and fully update your system, if not already:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade
sudo reboot
```

Check the log to see if the problem persists:

```
dmesg | grep iwl
```

Next, in your lsmod, we don't see iwlmvm. Is it loading correctly?

```
lsmod | grep iwl
```

If not, try loading it:

```
sudo modprobe iwlmvm
```

Is your /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf file properly completed? Mine reads:

```
# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
```

If it is not correct you will need to restore it. Let us know if you need guidance.

Finally, are there any interesting messages here?

```
dmesg | grep 84:00
dmesg | grep -i error
```

84:00 is the PCI bus for your wireless card. If there are ACPI or IRQ errors, you might try resetting the BIOS to Defaults.

Once we find some clues, I'll edit my answer as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'll add the information requested to the question.

Comment: I was able to get the system updated using chroot and the installation USB, no change to behavior however. :(

Comment: Updated using chroot? I don't understand. What does the installed version, the only one we need to see, say about firmware? ls -al /lib/firmware | grep 7260. What about your /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf file? Is it correct? With the updated kernel, do you still get the WARNING CPU message?

Comment: I updated using the USB installer, then chrooting to the target system.  See my answer for details.  I was able to work around the issue.  The firmware previously installed was -8.ucode not -7.ucode.  I'm marking your answer as accepted as a thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually fixed it by installing the 14.04 beta from scratch and then running an update before rebooting:

```
$ sudo su
# mount /dev/sda1 /target
# mount -o bind /dev /target/dev
# mount -o bind /sys /target/sys
# mount -o bind /tmp /target/tmp
# mount -o bind /proc /target/proc
# mount -o bind /etc/resolv.conf /target/etc/resolv.conf
# chroot /target
# apt-get update
# apt-get dist-upgrade
```