# Ubuntu 12.04 wireless constantly prompts for password with Intel 7260 and backports 3.11

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, intel-wireless, backport

When I first got my laptop I had the same problem as described in [No wireless for Intel Corporation 7260 version 63](https://askubuntu.com/questions/331667/no-wireless-for-intel-corporation-7260-version-63). I followed the instructions and everything worked perfectly for several months.

A few weeks ago I suddenly lost the ability to connect to my router, with the wireless icon stuck in the "connecting" animation and the password prompt repeatedly coming up. I am still able to connect fine using Windows on the same laptop and with my Mac. I've tried installing newer versions of the backports, to no effect. Here's some information about my setup.

```
$ uname -a
Linux l-i7537 3.8.0-38-generic #56~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 13 16:22:48 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lspci | grep Wireless
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 73)

$ lsmod | grep iwl
filename:       /lib/modules/3.8.0-38-generic/updates/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
version:        backported from Linux (v3.16-rc1-0-g7171511) using backports v3.16-rc1-1-0-g04d6077
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2014 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
version:        in-tree:d
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-9.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-9.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-9.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000-8.ucode
srcversion:     9E8CD8B5CABFCD8FF940D28
alias:          pci:v00008086d000024F4sv*sd00000030bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000024F3sv*sd00000010bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005490bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Bsv*sd00005290bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005590bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005190bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005090bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005420bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd0000502Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005020bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00009410bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00009310bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00009510bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00009200bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00009210bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00009112bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00009110bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00009012bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00009010bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Bsv*sd00005202bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005102bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005002bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Bsv*sd00005200bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd0000500Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005000bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00001010bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005400bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005410bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005412bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005012bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Bsv*sd00005210bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Bsv*sd00005302bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Bsv*sd00005310bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005100bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005110bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005010bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00001170bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00001070bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00008570bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00008470bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B4sv*sd00008270bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00008062bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00008060bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00008172bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00008170bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00008072bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00008070bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B4sv*sd00000370bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00000472bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00000470bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B4sv*sd00000272bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B4sv*sd00000270bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00000062bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00000060bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00000172bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00000170bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00000072bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00000070bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C420bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd0000C220bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C02Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C020bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C360bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd0000C370bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C560bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C570bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C462bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C460bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C472bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C470bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd0000C262bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd0000C26Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd0000C260bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd0000C272bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd0000C270bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C760bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C770bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C162bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C062bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C160bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C06Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C060bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C170bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C072bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C070bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004420bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd00004220bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000402Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004020bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00005770bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00005170bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00005072bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00005070bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd00004360bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd00004370bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004560bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004570bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004A6Cbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004A6Ebc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004A70bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000486Ebc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004870bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004462bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000446Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004460bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004472bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004470bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd00004262bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd0000426Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd00004260bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd00004272bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd00004270bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004162bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004062bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004160bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000406Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004060bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004170bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004072bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004070bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000892sv*sd00000462bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000893sv*sd00000262bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000892sv*sd00000062bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000894sv*sd00000822bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000894sv*sd00000422bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000895sv*sd00000222bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000894sv*sd00000022bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000088Fsv*sd00005260bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000088Esv*sd00004860bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000088Esv*sd0000446Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000088Esv*sd00004460bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000088Fsv*sd0000426Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000088Fsv*sd00004260bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000088Esv*sd0000406Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000088Esv*sd00004060bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000887sv*sd00004462bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000888sv*sd00004262bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000887sv*sd00004062bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000890sv*sd00004822bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000890sv*sd00004422bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000891sv*sd00004222bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000890sv*sd00004022bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000896sv*sd00005027bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000896sv*sd00005025bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000897sv*sd00005017bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000897sv*sd00005015bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000896sv*sd00005007bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000896sv*sd00005005bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008AEsv*sd00001027bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008AEsv*sd00001025bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008AFsv*sd00001017bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008AFsv*sd00001015bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008AEsv*sd00001007bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008AEsv*sd00001005bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000084sv*sd00001316bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000084sv*sd00001216bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000083sv*sd00001326bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000083sv*sd00001226bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000083sv*sd00001306bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000083sv*sd00001206bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000084sv*sd00001315bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000084sv*sd00001215bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000083sv*sd00001325bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000083sv*sd00001225bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000083sv*sd00001305bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000083sv*sd00001205bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000886sv*sd00001317bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000886sv*sd00001315bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000885sv*sd00001327bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000885sv*sd00001325bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000885sv*sd00001307bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000885sv*sd00001305bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000089sv*sd00001316bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000089sv*sd00001311bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000087sv*sd00001326bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000087sv*sd00001321bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000087sv*sd00001306bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000087sv*sd00001301bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000091sv*sd00005226bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000091sv*sd00005225bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000091sv*sd00005221bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000091sv*sd00005207bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000091sv*sd00005206bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000091sv*sd00005205bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000091sv*sd00005201bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000090sv*sd00005216bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000090sv*sd00005215bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000090sv*sd00005211bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000008Bsv*sd00005317bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000008Bsv*sd00005315bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000008Asv*sd00005327bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000008Asv*sd00005325bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000008Asv*sd00005307bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000008Asv*sd00005305bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001305bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001304bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00004820bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000085sv*sd0000C228bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000085sv*sd0000C220bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd0000C020bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000085sv*sd00001316bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000085sv*sd00001318bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000085sv*sd00001311bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001328bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001326bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001321bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001308bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001307bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001306bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001301bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004239sv*sd00001316bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004239sv*sd00001311bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004238sv*sd00001118bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004238sv*sd00001111bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Csv*sd00001326bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Csv*sd00001321bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Csv*sd00001307bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Csv*sd00001306bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Csv*sd00001301bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Bsv*sd00001128bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Bsv*sd00001121bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Bsv*sd00001108bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Bsv*sd00001101bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Dsv*sd00001316bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Dsv*sd00001216bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Dsv*sd00001311bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Dsv*sd00001211bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Csv*sd00001326bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Csv*sd00001321bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Csv*sd00001221bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Csv*sd00001306bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Csv*sd00001206bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Csv*sd00001301bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Csv*sd00001201bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Bsv*sd00001011bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Asv*sd00001021bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Asv*sd00001001bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004236sv*sd00001114bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004236sv*sd00001014bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004236sv*sd00001111bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004236sv*sd00001011bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004235sv*sd00001104bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004235sv*sd00001004bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004235sv*sd00001101bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004235sv*sd00001001bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004235sv*sd00001124bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004235sv*sd00001024bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004235sv*sd00001121bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004235sv*sd00001021bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004237sv*sd00001316bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004237sv*sd00001216bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004237sv*sd00001315bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004237sv*sd00001215bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004237sv*sd00001314bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004237sv*sd00001214bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004237sv*sd00001311bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004237sv*sd00001211bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001326bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001226bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001325bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001225bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001324bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001224bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001321bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001221bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001306bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001206bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001305bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001205bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001304bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001204bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001301bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001201bc*sc*i*
depends:        compat,cfg80211
vermagic:       3.8.0-38-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           debug:debug output mask (uint)
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size_8K:enable 8K amsdu size (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (defualt: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           wd_disable:Disable stuck queue watchdog timer 0=system default, 1=disable (default: 1) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality (default: N) (bool)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
```

Any advice would be appreciated. Please let me know if I can provide any additional information as well.

Comment: Does an older version of kernel work? If you haven't removed them, they'd still be available for booting in the Grub menu.

Comment: I tried that, the output here is actually from an older version of the kernel - I think the latest I have installed is 3.8.0-42, and I dropped down to 38 after I couldn't get things to work with 42.