# Asus Q302LA Wifi Problems: Intel Wireless 7260

Tags: asus, ubuntu-drivers

I'm using a live USB for Ubuntu and it's not detecting the Wifi connection on my Asus Q302LA.

I can't use an Ethernet cable because I don't have an Ethernet port on my laptop.

*How should I proceed?*

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need internet connection for installing the driver.

How much i know from our little chat, you have a Note 4 Android phone connected to your WiFi.

Try to set up USB Tethering on the phone and connect the phone to Ubuntu via USB cable, it should work out from the box for working internet connection.

Next step is on Ubuntu, go to System Settings->Software & Updates->Ubuntu Software Tab.

Check "Proprietary drivers for devices (restricted)"  and go to tab labeled "Additional Drivers" to check if there is a driver availible for your WiFi card.

Report back if solved or you need more info.

P.S.  if you are new to Ubuntu this guide is great for setting up a new system:

http://howtoubuntu.org/things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr

Comment: Ok that actually worked really well and was easy too lol.  I was concerned at first because I know sprint used to be extremely picky about their hot spots and tether going back a few years ago. Seems they loosen up a little lol. I did just as you described above and nothing came up. Any suggestions? Also another snag I ran into as I type my touch pad is enabled any quick setting I can turn off there? Thanks again for all your help me.

Comment: Ok, now you have a working internet connection on your Asus. thats good news. So you are a mouse user, go to System Settings->Mouse & Touchpad, there is a switch to turn off the Touchpad. Check the link I posted in my answer and do all steps trough. Report back after that.

Comment: While you complete the installs from the link, open a new terminal and write:  `lspci` and edit your question with the result of that command. EDIT: also run: `sudo lshw -c network`  and post the results.

Comment: LOL I messed up mate, you are running from Live CD. Your internet is working through android USB tethereing, correct?
In the guide link that i posted, do only Nr. 1,4,5,6 and 8 in that order. It has to find the drivers at some point.

Comment: whoops I read the post after I ran them all lol, will that be a problem? And Chrome won't install properly. Here are your results though.

Comment: ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 0a03 (rev 0b)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)

Comment: 00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA

Comment: I can't paste all its too long, and I can't chat I don't have enough rep LOL

Comment: I dont need the whole thing, only the part that states network. Check it and paste it. Also run `rfkill list` in terminal, check if all results are NO.

Comment: *-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: Wireless 7260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: cb
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f7c00000-f7c01fff

Comment: *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: usb0
       serial: 02:50:5d:04:61:63
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.107 link=yes multicast=yes

Comment: Mate, I have a feeling this will not work under Live CD bcs the new driver will not stick until you restart the hardware, so it will be deleted. Are you planing to install Ubuntu as main OS or in dual boot? Here is your solution:  http://askubuntu.com/a/331696/346680 but it cant be done from Live CD. Your WiFi card is "Intel Wireless 7260" and that is a good start after you install your system.

Comment: rfkill list came up clean I am noticing now though, my airplane mode hot key light is light

Comment: When I set up the usb I added persistence to it, will it apply with persistance?

Comment: LOL mate, then check the damn airplane mode :D Turn it off, turn WiFi on, run the "Additional Drivers" from system settings and report back.

Comment: Nothing there for the additional drivers and the key is pegged I can't remove it

Comment: You mean the Airplane Mode Key?

Comment: Yes normally on windows I hit the "FN" and "F2" key in sequence and it toggles it, I can't seem to get it work.

Comment: Boot to Windows, turn ON Wireless, shutdown Win, boot to Ubuntu Live CD, check the WiFi switches, read the link: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2242147
Google is your friend, and Live CD is for install and repair purposes, not a long term solution. You will have to install it in order to make it perfect.

Comment: I see, I was hoping I could use it on a long term basis, I'm debating how it would work with my insurance I have on this laptop. I know previously they would void if you installed another OS but I think i might try my luck and if anything happens ill pull the hard drive and wipe her clean.

Comment: The link you provided did give me good information. The initial path he provided failed to work so I'm going to actually install and then give it another try if that doesn't work, I don't mind tethering my data, I have unlimited 4G and most of the time I will be using this would be at home with actual WiFi. I'll report back to you. Also how do I give you Kudo's for all of your help here you have been fantastic man, seriously.

Comment: Normaly if a PC/Notebook gets broken, you send it to repair without the hard drive. So no worries about that.

I switched permanently 14 days ago and am happy not having to see Windows anymore ;) Good luck, i'm off to bed.

Comment: My answers are incomplete as much as your instalation of Ubuntu :P You can point the arrow up on my main answer, if you need anything else while installing, post a question. Best regards1

Comment: Well I installed it everything seemed fine, prompted me for a reboot, I did and windows boot driver completely took over and I didn't have the option to run Ubuntu. I partitioned my drive in case I ran into problems, very glad I did that now lol.

Comment: Ok, you are up for some Googling now how to make it dual boot ;)

Comment: Great news I got it figured out, there are some good guides online regarding this thanks for all your help

Comment: @JBeauvais Can you post a link to the guide you followed and/or add an answer laying out the steps you followed?

Comment: @Seth - probles with dual boot or with wireless?

Comment: @Zbunjeni Neither, I just want to get this question marked solved :)

Comment: Ahhh, you are the guy who keeps editing my comments all the time...ccc. :D

Comment: Zbunjeni you're a scholar and a gentleman - too bad the person you were giving tech support to for free didn't give you credit!  I want to buy one of these at best buy, and I guess it still isn't clear how much of a hassle it would be to keep this version of the Intel Wireless 7260 device working smoothly on ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Hey nealmcb! Thanks for nice words, I appreciate it! About the Intel 7269 Wireless, there are Linux Drivers provided by Intel to keep them running smooth! Check the link and you should be fine for good: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?DwnldID=17045    Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't stay connected to WiFi with my brand new ASUS Q302LA. I found the problem was the Network Adapter Driver. I downloaded the RALINK 5.0.47.0 driver from the ASUS website, and everything has worked GREAT since the driver update.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) Could you please give us a bit more information like: what's the link? What were the steps you took?  Please [edit] your question and add this information to make it a newbie answer so the next newbie on the block can actually use it!  Please?  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is reverting your kernel to the version 3.13.xx. I did it and now its working.

You can install it from the software center and use it with advanced options from the grub startup page.