# Toshibha Tecra wireless driver not detected

Tags: 12.04, wireless, realtek

Recently installed Ubuntu 12.04.05 on my new Toshiba Tecra Z40A, but the wireless adapter is not working / showing.

```
:~# lspci 
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 0a0c (rev 0b)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I218-V (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev e4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
**01:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5227 (rev 01)**
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 6b)
```

Can you please help in getting worked.

Comment: It seems that it's correctly detected by your kernel, how about the output of `rfkill list` from your terminal?

Comment: @P.-H.Lin

:~# rfkill list
1: Toshiba Bluetooth: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: no

1178: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: Here is your wireless device: `Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 6b)` The driver iwlwifi doesn't cover your device in 12.04. Please see here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/331667/no-wireless-for-intel-corporation-7260-version-63/331696#331696

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need backports for that card in 12.04

`sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential`

`wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v3.19-rc1/backports-3.19-rc1-1.tar.gz`

`tar -zxvf backports-3.19-rc1-1.tar.gz`

`cd backports-3.19-rc1-1`

`make defconfig-iwlwifi`

`make`

`sudo make install`

And you will need firmware

`wget https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/_media/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi-7260-ucode-23.15.10.0.tgz`

`tar zxvf iwlwifi-7260-ucode-23.15.10.0.tgz`

`sudo cp iwlwifi-*.ucode /lib/firmware`

Reboot

If you realize that your wifi doesn't work in the future, it is likely that a kernel update occured and you will need to

`cd backports-3.19-rc1-1`

`make clean`

`make defconfig-iwlwifi`

`make`

`sudo make install`

Reboot for wifi

Comment: Perfect! Awesome!! It worked charm. Thanks ton @Jeremy31