# WiFI not working on Asuspro laptop

Tags: wireless, intel-wireless

I am new on Ubuntu, and am running it off a pendrive on a Asuspro laptop. I cannot get the wireless to work, I cannot "enable wifi" even though I click on it.

I have read the other threads were others have similar problems, but they don't seem to work for me.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 0a2e (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I218-V (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 6b)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

Comment: Is it Asus or Acer?

Comment: And how did `acer-wireless` appear there?

Comment: @blade19899 It is another issue. See that it is blocked by a wrong platform driver.

Comment: @Pilot6 Did you try the answer posted there?

Comment: @NumbaCruncha Please [edit] your question and add output of `sudo dmidecode | grep "System Information" -A8`

Answer (score 0):

Run in terminal

```
sudo modprobe -r acer_wmi
sudo rfkill unblock all
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, try to do an upgrade on your system:
`sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade`
If it still does not work, try to see here:
https://askubuntu.com/a/331696/342147