# Ubuntu 18.04 No Wi-Fi Adapter Found on ThinkPad T440s

Tags: 18.04, thinkpad, intel-wireless

I'm new to Linux and I have just installed Ubuntu 18.04 having also Windows 10 as the second system and  my notebook is ThinkPad T440s. When I'm on Ubuntu, I can't access Wi-Fi because it shows that there is no Wi-Fi adapter. I did some research and I think that I don't have drivers or something but I can't download anything in terminal because I was using only Wi-Fi, I'm not having wire cable with Internet. I checked what is the name of my network controller in terminal and it's Intel Corporation Wireless 7260.

Output of `lshw -C network`:

```
*-network 
     description: Ethernet interface 
     product: Ethernet Connection I218-LM 
     vendor: Intel Corporation 
     physical id:19 
     bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0 
     logical name: enp0s25 
     version: 04 
     serial: 28:d2:44:5c:c0:aa 
     capacity: 1Gbit/s 
     width: 32bits 
     clock: 33Mhz 
     capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation 
     configuration: autonegotlation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.6-3 latency=0 link=no mu 
     resources: irq:43 memory:f06000000-f061ffff memory:f063e000-f063efff ioport:3080(size=32)

*-network UNCLAIMED 
     description: Network controller 
     product: Wireless 7260 
     vendor: Intel Corporation 
     physical id: 0 
     bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0 
     version: 83 
     width: 64 bits 
     clock: 33Mhz 
     capabilities: bus_master cap_list 
     configuration: latency=0 
     resources: memory:f0400000-f0401fff
```

Output of `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl`:

```
  modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.15.0-42-generic/modules.dep.bin'
  modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c514 lookup_builtin_file() could not open builtin file 'lib/modules/4.15.0-42-generic/modules.builtin.bin'
  modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.15.0-42-generic/modules.dep.bin'
  modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.15.0-42-generic/modules.dep.bin'
  modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:832 kmod_module_insert_module() could not find module by name='iwlwifi'
  modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'iwlwifi': Unkown symbol in module, or unkown parameter (see dmesg)
```

What can I do ?

Comment: it shows nothing :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No wireless for Intel Corporation 7260 version 63](https://askubuntu.com/questions/331667/no-wireless-for-intel-corporation-7260-version-63)

Comment: The usual driver and firmware for your device are included by default in 18.04. Let's try to load it and see what happens. Please run: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl` Next, edit your question to show the result. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 ok i did what You wanted, but only errors showed up

Comment: @chili555 Ok so i went to my friend and put internet cable to my notebook and did updates on system ( about 90 mb) and after this i wrote this command again and now it works, thanks a lot !! I also wrote here output after it worked, is output okay, no errors for future ?

Comment: @db14 Kindly add that as an answer and come back to site after 2 days to mark your answer as accepted :)

Comment: "I also wrote here output after it worked, is output okay, no errors for future ?" Looking very good. You are all set!

Comment: @Kulfy I agree. The answer should be much broader and explain that the main fix was likely installing all updates and rebooting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after installing all packets from Ubuntu I wrote this command and all drivers got downloaded

```
sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl

[    4.477277] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 17.948900127.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    4.509779] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7260, REV=0x144
[    4.533684] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: base HW address: 7c:7a:91:46:43:bc
[    4.756595] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    4.758792] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
```