# Intel Centrino 7260 after kernel update

Tags: 12.04, updates, kernel, intel-wireless

After every kernel update, will I need to redo everything from the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/322511/no-wireless-with-intel-centrino-advanced-n-7260)?

The reason I ask is because last night the kernel update but the wifi no longer works unless I load the previous kernel.

Will this be a perpetual problem with updating?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you must follow the steps for each kernel upgrade, fortunately they can be scripted and you can add any script you want to `/etc/kernel/postinst.d/` to be executed after each kernel update.

Another option would be to build a small script and put it in your /etc/rc.conf to check for the kernel module and build it if not present during boot, something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

module="iwlwifi"
check_module=$(modinfo $module 2>/dev/null)

if [ check_module != "ERROR: Module $module not found." ]; then
    echo "FAILED: $module not present in your kernel. Not loaded"
    module_make
    exit 0
else
    echo "PASSED: $module is loaded and present in this system"
    exit 0
fi

module_make{
        #pseudo steps, can' t figure out what exactly worked on the posted answer, to be completed later
    uncompress_file
    compile_module
    install_module
    exit 0
}
```

Created a new script with these contents, make it executable with `chmod +x wifi_script` and add it as a line in /etc/init.d/rc.local`or copy all the lines and add them directly to`/etc/init.d/rc.local`.

If the script detects that everything is ok and the module is loaded it will just boot your system normally, else it will download, extract, compile and load the module and continue to boot your system. Nothing fancy.

Comment: There was a discussion in a chat that had a link in the comments the first time I did this.  I followed the method from the chat.  However, the chat link is gone.  It was either in that post or one of the other linked posts but there isn't a chat link in those either.

Comment: @dustin where did the chat happen, general room?

Comment: It was one of the chats that says let's discuss here.  One usually gets the message to do so if there are too many comments.  I am not sure if that is helpful but that is all I know.

Comment: mmmh, can't find any relevant room talks... you dont remember what you did to make it for then, do you?

Comment: Care to try 13.10's livecd? its has the kernel version that the module is built from, maybe it works out of the box for you?

Comment: I need the cd?  I can't download and install?

Comment: Yes you can, but the livecd would let you see if the wireless is working out of the box without making any changes to your current system, besides, its the same cd as the install cd. Unless you wan to upgrade directly from your current system.