# Wireless not working.Toshiba P50-A-12z-. Artheoos. Ubuntu 12.04 (LTS)

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, atheros, toshiba-satellite

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 over a Toshiba P50-A-12z and after reformattting the disk with windows8 (I always kept windows before on a smaller partition but this time, windows8 was to bad even for me to keep so there it goes).

After doing a recommended upgrade of Ubuntu I solved some issues but I still am having problems with the wireless (I get a good wired connection though). Wireless used to work well with Windows8 before removing it from my system. I had to play with the BIOS to install Ubuntu from disk (disable the UEFI) but I doubt this should have any effect on the wireless performance. I tried many things I saw in this and other forums but nothing seems to work. I suspect the issue is on the driver that may not be available as on Intel's website say this device was released on the second half of 2013 and maybe too new for unsoported OS?. I checked on intel's webpage and even though they say the offer support for linux could not find the driver for what I think is my wireless device. Still, I hope a smart shoul from this forum could offer some help. 
Any help would be much appreciated. First, some useful info.

rfkill only shows bluetooth. Pressing F12 turns bluetooth on and off but no sign of wireless

```
rfkill list
5: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

lshw -C network shows the device is UNCLAIMED.

```
 *-network UNCLAIMED     
   description: Network controller
   product: Wireless 7260
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   version: 73
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:f7900000-f7901fff
  *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 10
   serial: 54:be:f7:73:00:bd
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx driverversion=1.2.3 duplex=full firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.105 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:19 memory:f7800000-f783ffff ioport:d000(size=128)
```

lspci shows what I think is the best description of the hardware. I should have checked this info from windows8 but now is too late. Is there other way of finding out if this is the hardware or can I trust the info from lspci?

```
lspci
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 73)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 10)
```

From my limited knowledge, I think the driver is alx (is it?). Below some info about it:

```
modinfo alx
filename:       /lib/modules/3.8.0-34-generic/kernel/ubuntu/alx/alx.ko
version:        1.2.3
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Qualcomm Atheros Gigabit Ethernet Driver
author:         Qualcomm Corporation, <nic-devel@qualcomm.com>
srcversion:     896F432F7919E2B2C08B0B3
alias:          pci:v00001969d000010A0sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d000010A1sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d00001090sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d00001091sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        mdio
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.8.0-34-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
```

Do I need to upgrade this driver or wait for a newer version?

```
Thanks!
```

Comment: The alx driver is for ethernet, which you say is working, so that is not the problem.

Comment: Check out the answer in
http://askubuntu.com/questions/322511/no-wireless-with-intel-centrino-advanced-n-7260

Comment: Yes, indeed! Also, the device is driven complete with firmware in Ubuntu 13.10. I suggest you try the live DVD and, if all goes well, install it.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED!**

Thanks a lot! I followed the solution posted by chili555 in the following link

http://[askubuntu.com/questions/331667/no-wireless-for-intel-corporation-7260-version-63](https://askubuntu.com/questions/331667/no-wireless-for-intel-corporation-7260-version-63)

And now my wireless works great. Again, thanks a lot. You guys rock!

PS. Don't get frustrated with people that don't find answers already posted in the forum. I spent hours browsing different solutions but could not find the right one until I was directed to it.

Just in case it helps to other non-expert people (like me) reading this post. My system (12.04) showed only up to /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode and no signs of the required 7260 that was needed for my intel device (see above). Now the 7260 ucode file is there. One obvious thing I tried a couple days ago was ubuntu 13 but could not even see the live CD (computer just stopped working in the middle of reading the DVD and I tried this multiple times with identical results).

I might ask your help again with my screen in the future (I think it has some compatibilty issues but works well for most prurposes so no urgency here) if I don't find a solution in the older posts.