# No wifi all of a sudden

Tags: 12.04, wireless

My wifi had been working fine, until 21:30 last night. From the logs it looks like it started to cycle connect/disconnect multiple times each minute, and then this morning it doesn't even appear to be trying to connect.

The cycle in `kern.log` looked like:

```
[38374.378692] userif-2: sent link down event.
[38374.378704] userif-2: sent link up event.<7>[38374.681807] bridge-wlan0: 
disabling the bridge on dev down
[38374.681841] bridge-wlan0: down
[38374.681855] bridge-wlan0: detached
[38374.689787] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[38374.881435] userif-2: sent link down event.
[38374.881444] userif-2: sent link up event.<6>[38375.530786] wlan0: authenticate
 with e0:a1:d7:d6:c3:b4
 [38375.531764] wlan0: send auth to e0:a1:d7:d6:c3:b4 (try 1/3)
[38375.533650] wlan0: authenticated
[38375.536171] wlan0: associate with e0:a1:d7:d6:c3:b4 (try 1/3)
 [38375.542840] wlan0: RX AssocResp from e0:a1:d7:d6:c3:b4 (capab=0x11 status=0 
aid=1)
 [38375.543974] wlan0: associated
 [38375.595428] /dev/vmnet: open called by PID 1518 (vmnet-bridge)
 [38375.595454] /dev/vmnet: hub 0 does not exist, allocating memory.
[38375.595488] /dev/vmnet: port on hub 0 successfully opened
[38375.595508] bridge-wlan0: device is wireless, enabling SMAC
[38375.595513] bridge-wlan0: up
 [38375.595553] bridge-wlan0: attached
```

and in `syslog` :

```
CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=e0:a1:d7:d6:c3:b4 reason=4
```

This morning, Upon boot-up it appears the `iwlwifi` module is now not loaded anymore, but adding it with `modprobe iwlwifi` didn't seem to help matters.

`lshw -C network` shows wireless as

```
*-network UNCLAIMED
    description: Network controller
    product: Wireless 7260
    vendor: Intel Corporation
    physical id: 0
    bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
    version: 73
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
    configuration: latency=0
    resources: memory:f0600000-f0601fff
```

and `iwconfig`:

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think I fixed this and know what went wrong. Although it doesn't explain the connect/reconnect cycling beforehand that was occurring.

From `/var/log/apt/history.log`:

```
Start-Date: 2014-01-04  00:28:01
Install: linux-headers-3.8.0-35:amd64 (3.8.0-35.50~precise1, automatic), linux-
image-3.8.0-35-generic:amd64 (3.8.0-35.50~precise1), linux-signed-image-
3.8.0-35-generic:amd64 (3.8.0-35.50~precise1), linux-headers-3.8.0-35-
generic:amd64 (3.8.0-35.50~precise1, automatic)
Upgrade: linux-image-generic-lts-raring:amd64 (3.8.0.34.34, 3.8.0.35.35),
linux-headers-generic-lts-raring:amd64 (3.8.0.34.34, 3.8.0.35.35), linux-
signed-generic-lts-raring:amd64 (3.8.0.34.34, 3.8.0.35.35), linux-signed-image-
generic-lts-raring:amd64 (3.8.0.34.34, 3.8.0.35.35), linux-libc-dev:amd64 
(3.2.0-57.87, 3.2.0-58.88), linux-generic-lts-raring:amd64 (3.8.0.34.34, 
3.8.0.35.35)
End-Date: 2014-01-04  00:29:16
```

It looks like late last night the kernel was updated automatically (for security updates are set to automatic on my system), and this is where the trouble started.

In order to get my Intel 7260 card working in the past on `Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS` with the raring kernel, I had to update my firmware as detailed [here](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=66001) and also backport the `iwlwifi` driver to work with this firmware from the 3.11 Kernel as detailed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/322511/no-wireless-with-intel-centrino-advanced-n-7260). Hence, I believe the updated kernel didn't have the backport and thus wifi died, hence to restore I simply applied the 3.11 backport to the new kernel:

0) Download latest firmware for 7260, if you don't already have it from [here](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi), and note the kernel needed to support it. Then in a terminal do:
`cp iwlwifi-*.ucode /lib/firmware`

1) Download backport from [here](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v3.11-rc3/backports-3.11-rc3-1.tar.bz2) to desktop and then extract.

2) Open terminal and do (more details on backporting [here](https://backports.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page))

```
cd Desktop/backports-3.11-rc3-1/
make defconfig-iwlwifi
make
sudo make install
```

Finally reboot.

Comment: Thanx, I looked for a fix in a long time and this worked too bad I can't send you a changetip here