# Can't establish wireless connection in Ubuntu 12.04.3

Tags: 12.04, wireless, dell

I have Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS running on Dell Inspiron 15R system. It does not find wireless connections at all. I tried to take help from numerous number of similar threads discussed on this forum([No wireless with Intel Centrino Advanced-N 7260](https://askubuntu.com/questions/322511/no-wireless-with-intel-centrino-advanced-n-7260)), but no luck.

Kernel information is as below:

```
debkumar@debkumarUbuntu:~$ uname -a
Linux debkumarUbuntu 3.8.0-35-generic #50~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 4 17:25:51 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

lshw:

```
debkumar@debkumarUbuntu:~$ sudo lshw -c network
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 07
       serial: 74:86:7a:5d:3d:28
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 ip=192.168.1.163 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:60 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b0600000-b0600fff memory:b0400000-b0403fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Wireless 7260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 73
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:b0500000-b0501fff
```

lspci:

```
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 05e9
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 60
    Region 0: I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
    Region 2: Memory at b0600000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Region 4: Memory at b0400000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
00: ec 10 36 81 07 04 10 00 07 00 00 02 10 00 00 00
10: 01 30 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 00 60 b0 00 00 00 00
20: 0c 00 40 b0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 28 10 e9 05
30: 00 00 00 00 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0b 01 00 00

02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 73)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless-N 7260
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 10
    Region 0: Memory at b0500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: wl
00: 86 80 b1 08 06 00 10 00 73 00 80 02 10 00 00 00
10: 04 00 50 b0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
20: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 86 80 62 44
30: 00 00 00 00 c8 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0a 01 00 00
```

rfkill list all:

```
debkumar@debkumarUbuntu:~$ rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I have also tried to load firmware as suggested by the following thread, but only disappointment.

[No wireless for Intel Corporation 7260 version 63](https://askubuntu.com/questions/331667/no-wireless-for-intel-corporation-7260-version-63)

I appreciate any suggestion in this regard!

Answer (score 0):

In order to diagnose the trouble, let's load the driver and see if an error is provoked:

```
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

If there is any error or warning, please post it. Next, let's check the message logs for any clues:

```
dmesg | grep iwl
```

Once we know the result, we can advise you further.

Comment: For sudo modprobe iwlwifi there is no error. I checked the message log for any entry of iwl, but no luck. However I can see following entries- debkumar@debkumarUbuntu:~$ dmesg | grep Wireless
[  110.171671] Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux, in-tree:

Comment: Please reboot and then: sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl