# Ubuntu 12.04: No Wifi Option

Tags: wireless

here's my problem: I have no wifi option showing up in the network manager... So I looked here (ask ubuntu) for the solution and there are hundreds of answers, but I just need one..

So I check for additional drivers from the system settings and it says no proprietary drivers (the card the box came in says it's linux capable)? So I find the hardware driver I need (from the ubuntu hardware driver page).. it's for a 7260AC wireless card.. I know it works cause I loaded it on here once before but for some reason, it disappeared.

So where can I find the answer on how to reload this driver to make it work again? I know it's on here somewhere.. I saved this in case the problem happened again but it's no longer there: askubuntu.com/questions/374165/ubuntu-12-04-no-wireless-after-install

Comment: Did you try this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/322511/no-wireless-with-intel-centrino-advanced-n-7260/

Comment: yes, that one looks familiar!! Thanx Chili!!

Comment: @user230289 Is it solved?

Answer (score 0):

While the instructions I linked should work perfectly for your device, there is a newer firmware file that corrects instability sometimes found with older firmware. With a working wired ethernet connection, please open a terminal and do:

```
cd /lib/firmware
sudo mv iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode  iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode.bak
sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/egrumbach/linux-firmware.git/plain/iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode
```

Unload and reload the driver so it sees and uses the newer firmware:

```
sudo modprobe -r iwldvm
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

Detach the ethernet and your wireless should be working.

If it still isn't working, check for informative clues:

```
dmesg | grep iwl
ls -al /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode
```

Comment: DAMN!! It didn't work.. It worked before at install.. this exact process.. I don't know why it disappeared in teh first place but I have a feeling that's why this happened in the first place... I was hoping I wouldn't have to load an entirely new system but it looks like I may have to.. this would be the 20th time I've had to do this, this year and this is my most stable ubuntu I've ever had :(

Comment: Please see my edit.