# NetworkManager doesn't see my wireless card

Tags: wireless, network-manager, intel-wireless

System details: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, kernel is 3.5.0-45-generic, laptop is Dell Sputnik 3 XPS 13, wireless card is Intel Wireless 7260(rev 6b)

I was having trouble connecting to my campus CS wireless but not any other networks. My sysadmin suggested using a fix from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/322511/no-wireless-with-intel-centrino-advanced-n-7260). I installed the backports in the accepted answer and rebooted. When I rebooted NetworkManager was not detecting my wireless card and the wlan0 interface was not up and running. I immediately uninstalled the backports but the issue persisted. I tried installing the drivers for my system from [here](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/19/ServiceTag/679BPY1?s=BSD) but that did not fix the issue either. I assume a factory restore would fix the problem, but I would prefer to avoid that.

In anticipation of requests for certain output:

lspci | grep Network

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 6b)
```

lshw -C network

```
*-network
    description: Network controller
    product: Wireless 7260
    vendor: Intel Corporation
    physical id: 0
    bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
    version: 6b
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: bus_master cap_list
    configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
    resources: irq:59 memory:f0400000-f0401fff
```

dmesg | grep iwl

```
[    7.675832] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: irq 59 for MSI/MSI-X
[    7.676309] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Selected bus type = PCI
[    7.845366] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 22.0.6.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    7.879810] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_start_tx_ba_cb_irqsafe
[    7.879814] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_start_tx_ba_cb_irqsafe (err -22)
[    7.879820] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_connection_loss
[    7.879822] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_connection_loss (err -22)
[    7.879827] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_report_wowlan_wakeup
[    7.879828] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_report_wowlan_wakeup (err -22)
[    7.879834] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_sched_scan_stopped
[    7.879836] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_sched_scan_stopped (err -22)
[    7.879865] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_free_hw
[    7.879866] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_free_hw (err -22)
[    7.879874] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_get_tkip_p2k
[    7.879876] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_get_tkip_p2k (err -22)
[    7.879881] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_alloc_hw
[    7.879883] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_alloc_hw (err -22)
[    7.879891] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_beacon_loss
[    7.879893] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_beacon_loss (err -22)
[    7.879904] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_register_hw
[    7.879906] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_register_hw (err -22)
[    7.879912] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_restart_hw
[    7.879914] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_restart_hw (err -22)
[    7.879917] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_rate_control_unregister
[    7.879919] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_rate_control_unregister (err -22)
[    7.879923] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol __ieee80211_get_radio_led_name
[    7.879925] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol __ieee80211_get_radio_led_name (err -22)
[    7.879943] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_wake_queue
[    7.879945] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_wake_queue (err -22)
[    7.879972] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_iter_keys
[    7.879974] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_iter_keys (err -22)
[    7.879988] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol wiphy_rfkill_set_hw_state
[    7.879990] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol wiphy_rfkill_set_hw_state (err -22)
[    7.880014] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_enable_rssi_reports
[    7.880015] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_enable_rssi_reports (err -22)
[    7.880019] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_stop_tx_ba_cb_irqsafe
[    7.880021] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_stop_tx_ba_cb_irqsafe (err -22)
[    7.880025] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_ave_rssi
[    7.880027] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_ave_rssi (err -22)
[    7.880033] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_sta_block_awake
[    7.880035] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_sta_block_awake (err -22)
[    7.880039] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_remain_on_channel_expired
[    7.880041] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_remain_on_channel_expired (err -22)
[    7.880056] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_wake_queues
[    7.880058] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_wake_queues (err -22)
[    7.880061] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_iterate_active_interfaces
[    7.880063] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_iterate_active_interfaces (err -22)
[    7.880066] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_rate_control_register
[    7.880068] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_rate_control_register (err -22)
[    7.880072] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_free_txskb
[    7.880074] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_free_txskb (err -22)
[    7.880094] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_tx_status
[    7.880096] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_tx_status (err -22)
[    7.880099] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_stop_queue
[    7.880101] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_stop_queue (err -22)
[    7.880108] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_ready_on_channel
[    7.880110] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_ready_on_channel (err -22)
[    7.880114] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_stop_queues
[    7.880116] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_stop_queues (err -22)
[    7.880130] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_sched_scan_results
[    7.880131] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_sched_scan_results (err -22)
[    7.880138] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_data_to_8023
[    7.880140] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_data_to_8023 (err -22)
[    7.880148] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_scan_completed
[    7.880150] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_scan_completed (err -22)
[    7.880153] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_iterate_active_interfaces_atomic
[    7.880155] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_iterate_active_interfaces_atomic (err -22)
[    7.880163] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol rate_control_send_low
[    7.880165] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol rate_control_send_low (err -22)
[    7.880173] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_unregister_hw
[    7.880175] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_unregister_hw (err -22)
[    7.880179] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_resume_disconnect
[    7.880181] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_resume_disconnect (err -22)
[    7.880189] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_beacon_get_tim
[    7.880191] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_beacon_get_tim (err -22)
[    7.880215] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol cfg80211_chandef_create
[    7.880217] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol cfg80211_chandef_create (err -22)
[    7.880221] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_request_smps
[    7.880223] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_request_smps (err -22)
[    7.880263] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_disable_rssi_reports
[    7.880265] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_disable_rssi_reports (err -22)
[    7.880279] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol mac80211_ieee80211_rx
[    7.880281] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol mac80211_ieee80211_rx (err -22)
[    7.880520] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: failed to load module iwlmvm (error 256), is dynamic loading enabled?
```

Content of /etc/network/devnames

```
wlan0:Intel Corporation Device 08b1
```

Content of /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

nm-tool

```
NetworkManager Tool

State: disconnected
```

If anyone could help me with this that would be awesome. The laptop doesn't have an ethernet port so I depend on the wireless working.

EDIT: chili555 helped me get this working via chat. The issue was Dell forces the laptop to use version 3.10 of the backports via DKMS. We removed that from DKMS then we installed 3.13. Note that every time a new kernel is installed 3.13 needs to be recompiled and reinstalled for the new kernel.

Comment: That's the same "fix" essentially that I linked to. It is what initially broke NM. I did install that firmware as well and it didn't fix the problem

Comment: I had a similar problem:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/440590/ubuntu-12-04-with-intel-corporation-wireless-7260-rev-73/442196#442196 However, I got an update today via ubuntu updates that made my card work! Perhaps you can remove your manually installed backports now as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So that we may troubleshoot, please go back to the backports file and do:

```
cd ~/Desktop/backports-3.11-rc3-1/
make clean
make-defconfig-iwlwifi
make > make.txt
```

Find the file make.txt in your user directory and paste it here and give us the link in your reply. I suspect there is an error at 'make' and I'd like to see it. http://paste.ubuntu.com

Also, install the newer firmware:

```
cd /lib/firmware
sudo mv iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode  iwlwifi-7260-7.bak
```

Get this file on another computer and, using a USB stick or similar, drag and drop the file to your desktop: https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/egrumbach/linux-firmware.git/plain/iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo cp iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode  /lib/firmware
```

Reboot.

Your 'make' looks just perfect. I suggest you install it:

```
cd ~/Desktop/backports-3.11-rc3-1/
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -r iwlmvm
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

Was a wireless interface created?

```
iwconfig
```

Check for informative messages:

```
dmesg | grep iwl
```

The correct firmware is:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  683236 Jan 17 11:34 iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode
```

Comment: Here is the paste http://paste.ubuntu.com/6887763/. I used the firmware you posted and that didn't fix it after reboot

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: No interface was created. dmesg | grep iwl shows a lot of information. It is here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6887855/

Comment: I see this: 'loaded firmware version 22.0.6.0 op_mode iwlmvm' That is the wrong firmware version. Please retrace your steps. The newest is firmware version 22.1.7.0. Let's see if the correct firmware corrects some or all of the errors.

Comment: Well I followed exactly what you said. There are multiple of those .ucode files in /lib/firmware but they are different versions. For the 7260 there are the one we put in (7260-7) and one the computer shipped with (7260-6). Besides those there are 14 others but not for the 7260

Comment: Let's see: ls -al /lib/firmware | grep 7260. According to lspci -nn, what is your pci.id? Is it 8086:08b1? If not, please post it.

Comment: The output of the dmesg command now finishes with request for firmware file 'iwlwifi-7260-6.ucode' failed no suitable firmware found! I moved the 7260-6 one to a backup file

Comment: The id is what you posted. Also like I said the only 7260 ones are iwlwifi-7260-6.ucode and iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode

Comment: May I see the ls -al /lib/firmware | grep 7260? Is the -7 version readable by all? The size I mentioned above? The -6 version needs to be moved to .bak.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12893/discussion-between-chili555-and-thaweatherman)

Answer (score 0):

Ok your laptop is supported by Ubuntu:

[Dell XPS13](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201309-14237/components/)

If you can connect to every other network apart from your Campus, then I would suggest that it's your Campus network that is the issue and not your laptop.

I would suggest you move back to your old firmware, maybe even with a fresh install and troubleshoot from there.

Then you can use wireshark to troubleshoot your network entry (both sides with help of your sysadmin), before you start changing drivers.

Additionally what is the issue with your connection i.e. are you getting a 169 address or 0.0.0.0 address or does it just refuse you network entry.

Note: The vendor of the access point can also create network entry issues.

Good luck