# Yoga Pro 2 Wi-Fi not working

Tags: wireless, networking, 14.04

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my new Yoga Pro 2 and the wireless is not working. It started with Windows 8 on it.

**The Network Manager says Wi-Fi is disabled by hardware switch.**

I tried putting a blacklist file in ect/modprobe.d as has been suggested in many places. I called the file "blacklist-ideapad_laptop.conf" and wrote in the file `blacklist ideapad_laptop`

I checked to make sure that the wireless is enabled in the BIOS. It is.

I ran `rfkill list all` and it displayed:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
         Soft blocked: no
         Hard blocked: no

2: phy0: Wireless LAN
         Soft blocked: no
         Hard blocked: yes
```

I ran `iwlist wlan0 scan` and it displayed:

```
wlan0    Failed to read scan data : Network is down
```

I ran `sudo rmmod ideapad_laptop` and it displayed:

```
rmmod: ERROR: Module ideapad_laptop is not currently loaded.
```

I ran `ifconfig wlp1s0 up` and it displayed:

```
wlp1s0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device.
```

I ran "lspci" and it displayed:

01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 6b)

I ran `sudo lshw -c network` and it displayed:

```
 *-network DISABLED
description: Wireless interface
product: Wireless 7260
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 0<br>
bus info: pci@0000:01:00:0.0
logical name: wlan0
version: 6b
serial: 7c:7a:91:5f:9b:fa
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.13.0-24-generic firmware=22.24.8.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
resources: irq:61 memory:b0400000-b0401fff
```

I ran dmesg | grep iwl an it displayed:

[   16.348702] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: irq 61 for MSI/MSI-X 
[   16.503224] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: loaded firmware version 22.24.8.0 op_mode iwlmvm 
[   16.522830] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wireless N 7260, REV=0x144 
[   16.522880] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S 
[   16.523095] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio. 
[   16.523110] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S 
[   16.535898] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs' 
[  488.563841] Modules linked in: rfcomm bnep nls_iso8859_1 hid_sensor_accel_3d hid_sensor_magn_3d hid_sensor_als hid_sensor_gyro_3d hid_sensor_trigger industrialio_triggered_buffer kfifo_buf industrialio hid_sensor_iio_common uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops rts5139(C) videobuf2_core hid_sensor_hub hid_multitouch videodev joydev arc4 iwlmvm mac80211 intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp snd_hda_codec_hdmi kvm snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hwdep psmouse snd_pcm serio_raw snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_page_alloc snd_seq lpc_ich btusb bluetooth iwlwifi snd_seq_device snd_timer cfg80211 snd soundcore mei_me mei mac_hid parport_pc ppdev lp parport usbhid hid dm_crypt crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel i915 aesni_intel aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper drm ahci libahci video 
[  490.188258] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio. 
[  492.366192] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: no hotplug settings from platform 
[ 3921.859535] Modules linked in: rfcomm bnep nls_iso8859_1 hid_sensor_accel_3d hid_sensor_magn_3d hid_sensor_als hid_sensor_gyro_3d hid_sensor_trigger industrialio_triggered_buffer kfifo_buf industrialio hid_sensor_iio_common uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops rts5139(C) videobuf2_core hid_sensor_hub hid_multitouch videodev joydev arc4 iwlmvm mac80211 intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp snd_hda_codec_hdmi kvm snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hwdep psmouse snd_pcm serio_raw snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_page_alloc snd_seq lpc_ich btusb bluetooth iwlwifi snd_seq_device snd_timer cfg80211 snd soundcore mei_me mei mac_hid parport_pc ppdev lp parport usbhid hid dm_crypt crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel i915 aesni_intel aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper drm ahci libahci video 
[ 3923.293746] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio. 
[ 3925.438830] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: no hotplug settings from platform 
[10046.688939] Modules linked in: rfcomm bnep nls_iso8859_1 hid_sensor_accel_3d hid_sensor_magn_3d hid_sensor_als hid_sensor_gyro_3d hid_sensor_trigger industrialio_triggered_buffer kfifo_buf industrialio hid_sensor_iio_common uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops rts5139(C) videobuf2_core hid_sensor_hub hid_multitouch videodev joydev arc4 iwlmvm mac80211 intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp snd_hda_codec_hdmi kvm snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hwdep psmouse snd_pcm serio_raw snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_page_alloc snd_seq lpc_ich btusb bluetooth iwlwifi snd_seq_device snd_timer cfg80211 snd soundcore mei_me mei mac_hid parport_pc ppdev lp parport usbhid hid dm_crypt crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel i915 aesni_intel aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper drm ahci libahci video 
[10048.562700] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio. 
[10050.754394] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: no hotplug settings from platform

This [No wireless with Intel Centrino Advanced-N 7260](https://askubuntu.com/questions/322511/no-wireless-with-intel-centrino-advanced-n-7260) seems to be dealing with a similar issue. It suggests that I need to update my firmware. So I downloaded iwlwifi-7260-ucode-23.214.9.0 from Intel's website. I put the file "iwlwifi-7260-9.ucode" in /lib/firmware and ran "sudo lshw -c network" again. It displayed exactly as before.

After moving iwlwifi-7260-9.ucode to /lib/firmware I ran "sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi" and "sudo modprobe iwlwifi"

Is there something else I need to do install the new firmware?

Comment: Yes, it seems to have no effect.

Comment: I haven't had any success with [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/367963/ubuntu-on-lenovo-yoga-2-pro) or [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/322511/no-wireless-with-intel-centrino-advanced-n-7260) thus far. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick idea but try the following code:

```
rfkill unblock 2
```

I See that you have a blocked wireless